# Javascript: formatting a rounded number to N decimals

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, decimal-point

in JavaScript, the typical way to round a number to N decimal places is something like:

```js
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
  return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
}
```

```js
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
  return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
}

console.log(roundNumber(0.1 + 0.2, 2));
console.log(roundNumber(2.1234, 2));
```

However this approach will round to a *maximum* of N decimal places while I want to *always* round to N decimal places. For example "2.0" would be rounded to "2".

Any ideas?

Comment: normally, you could use `toFixed()` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToFixed ), but it's buggy in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript/661757#661757 ; you'll have to write your own version...

Comment: @hoju - perhaps change accepted answer - David's answer is correct for IE8+, while the accepted answer has some serious bugs on all browsers.

Comment: @robocat: Are you serious?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's not a rounding ploblem, that is a display problem. A number doesn't contain information about significant digits; the value 2 is the same as 2.0000000000000. It's when you turn the rounded value into a string that you have make it display a certain number of digits.

You could just add zeroes after the number, something like:

```
var s = number.toString();
if (s.indexOf('.') == -1) s += '.';
while (s.length < s.indexOf('.') + 4) s += '0';
```

(Note that this assumes that the regional settings of the client uses period as decimal separator, the code needs some more work to function for other settings.)

Comment: toFixed is buggy..for instance the decimal: 1.02449999998
if u do dec.toFixed(4) => 1.0244. It should have been 1.0245 instead.

Comment: @deepeshk But what would be the problem with using `toFixed()` to pad decimals at the end, after rounding?

Comment: @deepeshk in what browser? Just tried it in Chrome 17 and `1.02449999998.toFixed(4)` correctly returns `1.0245`.

Comment: @Mark got most of the answer, but after some research you need to call it like this, `Number(float).toFxied(places);`.

Comment: @MarkTomlin: Then it seems that you have a string instead of a number.

Comment: @Guffa thanks' for the clarification, I'm kinda fumbling my way through JavaScript programming right now. +1.

Comment: As an FYI, if you only need precision to 2 decimal places .toFixed works for both IE and Chrome.

Comment: .toFixed() works brilliantly in modern browsers (I tested Chrome, Firefox, IE11, IE8). @Bat_Programmer - please clarify *which* browsers you think have that bug.

Comment: @robocat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript/661757#661757

Comment: `.toFixed()` is fixed in IE8+ (my testing) but apparently buggy in IE7 (as per @Guffa link in comment above - thank you). So **use** toFixed() unless you need to support IE7 ;-)

Comment: Do NOT USE this answer because it has serious bugs: it gives incorrect answers: NaN -> NaN.000, Infinity -> Infinity.000, 9e60 -> 9E60.000, 0.000001 -> 0.000001 (0.000001.toFixed(3) correctly gives 0.000).

Comment: @robocat: Are you serious?

Comment: @Guffa - `.toFixed()` works *correctly* in IE8+. e.g. I just run IE8 using the example from the link of `(0.595).toFixed(2)` and got correct answer of `0.60`. Your code is broken for corner cases (the few I thought of from the top of my head with a few minutes testing, I could probably find other things wrong with it), and is not suitable for production code IMHO.

Comment: @robocat: You are looking for something that I never claimed that the code would be. Besdies, you can just as easily find corner cases where `toFixed` is broken, for example `(1000000000000000000000).toFixed(3)` returns `1e+21` not `1000000000000000000000.000`.

Comment: @MattBall no it doesn't, it returns `"1.0245"`

Comment: sorry lovely peopls  please stop saying toFixed returns a number. `5 + (3).toFixed(2)` returns `"53.00"`

Comment: @Guffa incorrect. it returns `"1e+21"` . And your comment doesn't show you  know what `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`  is.

Answer (score 297):

I think that there is a more simple approach to all given here, and is the method `Number.toFixed()` already implemented in JavaScript.

simply write:

```
var myNumber = 2;

myNumber.toFixed(2); //returns "2.00"
myNumber.toFixed(1); //returns "2.0"
```

etc...

Comment: Where is mentioned, hoju? I reviewed other answers and I didn't find anyone reporting that toFixed function is buggy. Thanks

Comment: @David: That's mentioned in a comment to the answer, for example.

Comment: caution: `toFixed()` returns a string.

Comment: @JordanArseno this can be fixed using parseInt(myNumber.toFixed(intVar)); to return an integer value, or parseFloat(myNumber.toFixed(floatVar));  to return a float if user has decimal places.

Comment: I don't agree this being a correct answer. It returns a string, not a number. So it doesn't round a number to N decimals, it creates a string that humans can read as a number with decimals. But ony if they, by accident, use the same sign for decimals.
use parseFloat(myNumber.toFixed(2));  to get a float of your number (And hope for the best, rounding issues might occur)

Comment: What about ``var myNumber = 2.1; myNumber.toFixed(18)``

Comment: Javascript magic @CrazyGreenHand

Comment: WARNING toFixed will convert 2.085 to 2.08, it doesn't round properly at least in Chrome Version 121.0.6167.184

Answer (score 52):

I found a way. This is Christoph's code with a fix:

```
function toFixed(value, precision) {
    var precision = precision || 0,
        power = Math.pow(10, precision),
        absValue = Math.abs(Math.round(value * power)),
        result = (value < 0 ? '-' : '') + String(Math.floor(absValue / power));

    if (precision > 0) {
        var fraction = String(absValue % power),
            padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');
        result += '.' + padding + fraction;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Read the details of repeating a character using an array constructor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times/1877479#1877479) if you are curious as to why I added the "+ 1".

Comment: Passing in a value of 708.3333333333333 with a precision of 2 or 3 results in a return value of 708.00 for me.  I need this for 2 decimal places, in Chrome and IE 9 .toFixed(2) met my needs.

Comment: this is not a common way, e.g, toFixed(16.775, 2) return 16.77. Convert number to String then convert is the only way.

Comment: There is a bug with this method: toFixed(-0.1111, 2) returns 0.11, i.e. the negative sign is lost.

Comment: Works great, except for that I have added parseFloat(result) at the end. Worth an edit.

Answer (score 21):

There's always a better way for doing things. Use [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) -

```
var number = 51.93999999999761;
```

I would like to get four digits precision: 51.94

just do:

```
number.toPrecision(4);
```

the result will be: 51.94

Comment: And what if you add 100? Do you need to change it to number.toPrecision(5)?

Comment: Yes. 31.939383.toPrecision(4) > "31.94" / 131.939383.toPrecision(4) > "131.9"

Comment: for negative numbers, it changes by 1 decimal. Is there some solution to it?

Comment: Note that this doesn't round to n decimals, it rounds to n *sigfigs* and it returns a string. for example, `(1234.56789).toPrecision(4)` returns `1235` NOT `1234.5679`

Comment: Sorry peops, this is not the correct anser, the question is about decimals.
number.toPrecision(4); does not always give 4 decimals.

Answer (score 8):

```js
function roundton(num, n) {
    return Number(num.toFixed(n));
}
```

This uses JS's built-in method [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) which is meant for formatting strings but allows us to round to a specific number of digits. the [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) call converts it back to a number object cleanly

Ideally, we wouldn't need to convert it to a string, but [`toFixed` is written in native C++ doing basic cstring operations](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/a8cb3cef03aea1d119e00d256cc6993acd46f49b/src/numbers/conversions.cc#L1131-L1198) so it's likely still fast.

Comment: This is by far the best answer here.

Comment: I think this is the only correct answer. It's clean, it does all the work in machine-language. I would not even bother to create a function but just paste it in where I need it, so my colleagues can see it returns a number.

Answer (score 7):

This works for rounding to N digits (if you just want to truncate to N digits remove the Math.round call and use the Math.trunc one):

```
function roundN(value, digits) {
   var tenToN = 10 ** digits;
   return /*Math.trunc*/(Math.round(value * tenToN)) / tenToN;
}
```

Had to resort to such logic at Java in the past when I was authoring [data manipulation E-Slate components](http://e-slate.cti.gr/Components.htm#Variation). That is since I had found out that adding 0.1 many times to 0 you'd end up with some unexpectedly long decimal part (this is due to floating point arithmetics).

A user comment at [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places/34796988) calls this technique scaling.

Some mention there are cases that don't round as expected and at http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ this is suggested instead:

```
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}
```

Comment: btw, POSITS are promising for future h/w architectures: https://www.nextplatform.com/2019/07/08/new-approach-could-sink-floating-point-computation/

Comment: This is the correct answer, properly rounds 2.085 to 2.09

Answer (score 5):

#### PHP-Like rounding Method

The code below can be used to add your own version of Math.round to your own namespace which takes a precision parameter. Unlike Decimal rounding in the example above, this performs no conversion to and from strings, and the precision parameter works same way as PHP and Excel whereby a positive 1 would round to 1 decimal place and -1 would round to the tens.

```
var myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.round = function(number, precision) {
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var tempNumber = number * factor;
    var roundedTempNumber = Math.round(tempNumber);
    return roundedTempNumber / factor;
};

myNamespace.round(1234.5678, 1); // 1234.6
myNamespace.round(1234.5678, -1); // 1230
```

from [Mozilla Developer reference for Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully working code (didn't do much testing):

```
function toFixed(value, precision) {
    var precision = precision || 0,
        neg = value < 0,
        power = Math.pow(10, precision),
        value = Math.round(value * power),
        integral = String((neg ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(value / power)),
        fraction = String((neg ? -value : value) % power),
        padding = new Array(Math.max(precision - fraction.length, 0) + 1).join('0');

    return precision ? integral + '.' +  padding + fraction : integral;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a bug. I tried toFixed(2.01, 4) and got a result of "2.100". If I ever find a way to fix it, I will post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: @mikez302: the padding computation was off by one; should work now, but feel free to bug me again if it's still broken...

Comment: Very strange. When I run this fuction with the firebug console open in firefox 17 it freezes the whole browser like js is caught in an endless loop. Even if i do not console.log the output. If I do not have firebug activated the bug does not occur.

Comment: Update, i ran it in chrome and i get: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in regards to the toFixed function call.

Comment: @SublymeRick: I have no idea why this happens; shot in the dark: try renaming the function...

Comment: @Christoph, I believe it is happening because of stacking all vars and calculations with comma on a single var statement. It breaks the debugger, but works in browser.I had similar case with a larger script, if I remember correctly on Firefox 42

Answer (score 1):

I think below function can help

```
function roundOff(value,round) {
   return (parseInt(value * (10 ** (round + 1))) - parseInt(value * (10 ** round)) * 10) > 4 ? (((parseFloat(parseInt((value + parseFloat(1 / (10 ** round))) * (10 ** round))))) / (10 ** round)) : (parseFloat(parseInt(value * (10 ** round))) / ( 10 ** round));
}
```

usage : `roundOff(600.23458,2);` will return `600.23`

Answer (score 0):

```
function round(number,decimals) {
  var value = Math.abs(number).toString().toLowerCase().split("e");
  var step = !value.includes('e') ? (value[0] + 'E' + decimals) : (value[0] + 'E' + (+value[1] + decimals));
  var sign = Math.sign(number)<0?"-":"";
  var exponent = (Math[(step % 2 <= .5 || (step % 2 >= 1 && step % 2 < 1.5))?'floor':'ceil'](typeof(value[1]) == 'undefined' ? (value[0] + 'E' + decimals) : (value[0] + 'E' + (+value[1] + decimals))))["toString"]().toLowerCase().split("e")[1];
  return sign + (Math.abs(number) >= 1E21 ? Math.abs(number)["toString"]().toLowerCase().split("e")[0].replace(".","").padEnd(+exponent-1,0) : +((Math[(step % 2 <= .5 || (step % 2 >= 1 && step % 2 < 1.5))?'floor':'ceil'](typeof(value[1]) == 'undefined' ? (value[0] + 'E' + decimals) : (value[0] + 'E' + (+value[1] + decimals))))["toString"]().toLowerCase().split("e")[0].replace('.','').padEnd(+exponent+1,0) + (decimals==0?"":"E" + -decimals)));
}

console.log(round(1.492,2)); // 1.49
console.log(round(1.499245,5)); // 1.49924
console.log(round(-3.0e-7,5)); // -0
console.log(round(-0.00000050001,6)); // -0.000001
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do not really care about rounding, just added a toFixed(x) and then removing trailing 0es and the dot if necessary. It is not a fast solution.

```
function format(value, decimals) {
    if (value) {
        value = value.toFixed(decimals);            
    } else {
        value = "0";
    }
    if (value.indexOf(".") < 0) { value += "."; }
    var dotIdx = value.indexOf(".");
    while (value.length - dotIdx <= decimals) { value += "0"; } // add 0's

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I tried `format(1.2, 5)` and got `1.2`, while I expected `1.20000`.

Comment: Sorry @EliasZamaria , didn't understand it at first. I have edited the post. Just note that it wil return "0.0000" when value is undefined.