# JavaScript displaying a float to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I wanted to display a number to 2 decimal places.

I thought I could use `toPrecision(2)` in JavaScript .

However, if the number is `0.05`, I get `0.0500`. I'd rather it stay the same.

See it on [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/eguvo/edit).

What is the best way to do this?

I can think of coding a few solutions, but I'd imagine (I hope) something like this is built in?

Answer (score 847, accepted):

```
float_num.toFixed(2);
```

**Note:**[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will round or pad with zeros if necessary to meet the specified length.

Comment: But it returns string, not float!

Comment: Question author wants to "display" it, so a string is perfect

Comment: And you can always use parseFloat(float_num.toFixed(2)) to convert the string back to float while keeping only two decimals.

Comment: @anwar you can't reliably round a float (arguably you can round a float at all) - you'll get something like 0.0500 or even 0.0500000000001. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Hankrecords what you said is not true. If i have '43.01' and I parseFloat then i get 43.01 BUT if i have '43.10' i will get 43.1 :D not what I want.

Comment: @LucianTarna By "while keeping only two decimals" I meant that you won't have more than two. You can't have a 0 as the last decimal digit in a float, it will always truncate. That's why `float_num.toFixed(2)` is needed.

Comment: @Anwar, if you need a float value, this maybe a better answer for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/2125572

Comment: jmc's comment is worth highlighting.  It's not possible to represent some floating point values with a finite number of decimal values.  The decimal rounding should always be upon converting *from* float to some form of fixed point or decimal value - such as a string, BCD, fixed point integer, but not back to float.  Also worth mentioning that float - and therefore Javascript Number - is not suitable for monetary values due to this, unless shifting the integral to the smallest unit of currency (eg count cents, not dollars).

Comment: float_num.toFixed(2) returns string, so just run parseFloat: float_num =parseFloat(float_num.toFixed(2))

Answer (score 54):

You could do it with the `toFixed` function, but it's [buggy in IE](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=102421). If you want a reliable solution, look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/round-number-in-javascript-to-n-decimal-places/2909252#2909252).

Comment: Technology should be developed rather than adapt to IE... (btw. in node js `float_num.toFixed(2);` works fine)

Comment: IE died yesterday..

Answer (score 43):

with `toFixed` you can set length of decimal points like this:

```js
let number = 6.1234
number.toFixed(2) // '6.12'
```

but `toFixed` returns a string and also if `number` doesn't have decimal point at all it will add redundant zeros.

```js
let number = 6
number.toFixed(2) // '6.00'
```

to avoid this you have to convert the result to a number. you can do this with these two methods:

```js
let number1 = 6
let number2 = 6.1234

// method 1
parseFloat(number1.toFixed(2)) // 6
parseFloat(number2.toFixed(2)) // 6.12

// method 2
+number1.toFixed(2) // 6
+number2.toFixed(2) // 6.12
```

Answer (score 40):

`number.parseFloat(2)` works but it returns a string.

If you'd like to preserve it as a number type you can use:

`Math.round(number * 100) / 100`

Comment: The internal representation of this might not be what you want. And most likely is something you don't want to be bothered with - representation (and storage) is important. Think of it the same way as you do with booleans.

Answer (score 33):

Don't know how I got to this question, but even if it's many years since this has been asked, I would like to add a quick and simple method I follow and it has never let me down:

```
var num = response_from_a_function_or_something();

var fixedNum = parseFloat(num).toFixed( 2 );
```

Comment: Why `parseFloat()` there? It should only be used if the number is coming from a string.

Comment: In some occasions when I get some "data-" attribute value with jquery from an element, if I use only toFixed it produces an error. parseFloat fixes it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant above *if it came from a string*. But using it always is bad advice.

Answer (score 25):

Try [`toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) instead of `toPrecision`.

Answer (score 18):

`function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}`

> round(1.005, 2); // return 1.01
>
> round(1.004, 2); // return 1 instead of 1.00

The answer is following this link: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

Answer (score 13):

I used this way if you need 2 digits and not string type.

```js
    const exFloat = 3.14159265359;
    
    console.log(parseFloat(exFloat.toFixed(2)));
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try mixing `Number()` and `toFixed()`.

Have your target number converted to a nice string with X digits then convert the formated string to a number.

`Number( (myVar).toFixed(2) )`

---

See example below:

```js
var myNumber = 5.01;
var multiplier = 5;
$('#actionButton').on('click', function() {
  $('#message').text( myNumber * multiplier );
});

$('#actionButton2').on('click', function() {
  $('#message').text( Number( (myNumber * multiplier).toFixed(2) ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="actionButton">Weird numbers</button>
<button id="actionButton2">Nice numbers</button>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for You nice reference.

Comment: Very good answer, it preserves when the number is integer, and adjusts when it's float

Answer (score 4):

> The `toFixed()` method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

and here is the syntax

```
numObj.toFixed([digits])
```

**digits** argument is optional and by default is 0. And the return type is string not number. But you can convert it to number using

```
numObj.toFixed([digits]) * 1
```

It also can throws exceptions like `TypeError`, `RangeError`

Here is the [full detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) and compatibility in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

```
let a = 0.0500
a.toFixed(2);

//output
0.05
```

Comment: No, the output is `"0.05"` (running in Chrome dev tools), which is not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `Intl` API to format decimals according to your locale value. This is important specially if the decimal separator isn't a dot "." but a comma "," instead, like it is the case in Germany.

```
Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').formatToParts(0.05).reduce((acc, {value}) => acc += value, '');
```

Note that this will round to a maximum of 3 decimal places, just like the `round()` function suggested above in the default case. If you want to customize that behavior to specify the number of decimal places, there're  options for minimum and maximum fraction digits:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits: 3}).formatToParts(0.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float_num = parseFloat(float_num.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Please include some explanation, code only answers are unhelpful

Answer (score -2):

I have made this function. It works fine but returns string.

```
function show_float_val(val,upto = 2){
  var val = parseFloat(val);
  return val.toFixed(upto);
}
```