# Listen for blank inputs and add a "disabled" attribute to a button until an input is noticed

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have a user input field that, if blank, I would like the submit button to be disabled until a key press in the input box is noticed. But, if they blank out the input box, then the button is disabled again.

So, I'd like to add the "disabled" attribute to this input button:

```
<input type="submit" id="mapOneSubmit" value="Submit" [add attribute "disabled" here]>
```

The input is from this HTML here:

```
<input type="text" id="mapOneUserInput" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" oninput="validate(this)">
```

Note: I have onkeypress and oninput validation to prevent non-number inputs and allow only 2 decimal places.

I assume my JS would look like this to add the disabled attribute:

```
document.getElementById("mapOneSubmit").setAttribute("disabled");
```

My problem is, I can't find what event listener listens for "blank" inputs? Can you help me with that?

Thanks kindly!

Comment: in your function ```isNumberKey``` add this code snipped ```console.log(event.which)``` and start typing (blank inputs) which you have mentioned. I hope you will find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one as well.

```js
function checkvalid(el)
{
//e.g i am preventing user here to input only upto 5 characters
//you can put your own validation logic here
if(el.value.length===0 || el.value.length>5)
document.getElementById("mapOneSubmit").setAttribute("disabled","disabled"); 
else
document.getElementById("mapOneSubmit").removeAttribute('disabled'); 

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id ='inp' onkeyup='checkvalid(this)'>
<button id='mapOneSubmit' disabled>
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet using the input event:

```
<input type="text" id="mapOneUserInput" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" oninput="validate(this);updateSubmit(this.value)">
```

Then in js

```
function updateSubmit(val) {
    if (val.trim() == '') {
         document.getElementById('mapOneSubmit').disabled = true;
    }
    else {
         document.getElementById('mapOneSubmit').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it should work... but for the life of me, I just can't get this to cooperate at all!

Comment: No, not at all from what I can see in the console log

Comment: And I just tried a jsbin https://jsbin.com/tubawaz/edit?html,js,output and it also didn't seem to work there. But I was being a bit sloppy.

Comment: Did you add a console.log in it to make sure? Try changing the order as it could be that your validate function throws exception `<input type="text" id="mapOneUserInput" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" oninput="updateSubmit(this.value)` in this I removed it totally.

Comment: I did, and it wasn't working. At this point I really do not know why, because this looked like it should. But I was able to get it to work with another method above. Thanks though, I probably could spend some more time on working out why this didn't work. But now I have something in place... I best move on to the next problem :P (there's a few to go).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the below code to find the blank inputs

```js
function isNumberKey(event) {
  console.log(event.which)
}
var value;
function validate(target) {
  console.log(target);

  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="mapOneUserInput" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" oninput="validate(this)">
  <input type="submit" id="mapOneSubmit" value="Submit" [add attribute "disabled" here]>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you set the enable/disable inside validate function.

```
function validate(elem) {
  //validation here

  //code to disable/enable the button 
  document.getElementById("mapOneSubmit").disabled = elem.value.length === 0;
}
```

Set the button disable on load by adding disabled property

```
<input type="submit" id="mapOneSubmit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your validate function just check if value of input field is blank then enable/disable the button

```
function validate(input){
  input.disabled = input.value === "" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is, I can't find what event listener listens for "blank" inputs?

You can disable the submit button at render, after that you can use the `input` event to determine whether the input value is empty or not. From there, you can set state of the submit button.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('mapOneUserInput');
  textInput.addEventListener('input', handleTextInput, false);
  textInput.addEventListener('keydown', validateInput, false);
});

function handleTextInput(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  if (value) {
    enableSubmitButton(true);
  } else {
    enableSubmitButton(false);
  }
}

// Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203928/7583537
function validateInput(event) {
  const regex = /^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;
  const prevVal = event.target.value;
  const input = this;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    var nextVal = event.target.value;
    if (!regex.test(nextVal)) {
      input.value = prevVal; 
    }
  }, 0);
}

function enableSubmitButton(isEnable) {
  const button = document.getElementById('mapOneSubmit');
  if (isEnable) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="" id="mapOneUserInput">

<!-- Note that the input blank at render so we disable submit button -->
<input type="submit" id="mapOneSubmit" value="Submit" disabled>
```