# I have a number input and I want to convert into decimal react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert a input type number into two decimal values in the form values, but show to user only integer when there is no decimal.
for eg 1 -> 1.00 , 2.346 -> 2.34
As in the first example it should show to user only 1 but in the form values it should be 1.00

```js
<Input
  {...field}
  onKeyDown={e => decimalPlace(e, form)}
  type="number"
  step={0.01}
  value={minVal}
  onChange={e => {
    form.handleChange(e);
  }}
  id="price"
  isDisabled={isSubmitting}
/>
```

As I am using chakra and formik, minVal here is a state which I set in decimalPlace function like below

```
form.setFieldValue('targetPriceMin', Number(e.target.value).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: can you share your form code?

Comment: yes a min @AlanOmar

Comment: Javascript will coerce `1.00` to `"1"` since the input is technically working with strings and *not* numbers. You can, however, format your input value, i.e. something like `Number(value).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried that but as I have type='number' it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow 2 decimal places in <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number)

Comment: What doesn't work? Can we see what you've tried? Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. FYI, `type="number"` has nothing to do with the type of the variable, it hints to the browser what keyboards to display (if any) and how to handle some basic level of input validation, i.e. min/max/step, etc...

Comment: I have added code @DrewReese

Comment: @pilchard that does not work

Comment: @DrewReese can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Format the value when it is passed to the input.

```
<Input
  {...field}
  onKeyDown={(e) => decimalPlace(e, form)}
  type="number"
  step={0.01}
  value={Number(minVal).toFixed(2)} // <-- format here for display
  onChange={(e) => {
    form.handleChange(e);
  }}
  id="targetPriceMin"
  isDisabled={isSubmitting}
/>
```

[image: Edit i-have-a-number-input-and-i-want-to-convert-into-decimal-react-js]

Code in sandbox uses vanilla input but principle is the same.

```
<input
  type="number"
  min={0}
  max={10}
  step={0.01}
  value={Number(value).toFixed(2)}
  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Not able to clear properly the decimal places using this

Comment: @Abhishek Can you clarify what you mean by not being able to "clear properly the decimal places"? Think you could provide a *running* codesandbox with *your* component code that reproduces the issue that we may live debug in?