# dash plotly bootstrap number input placing

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

So I want to place my text box as shown
[image]

However, my code doesn't work and show me this instead
[image]

Heres my coding:

```
html.H1("Query1", style={'text-align': 'center','fontSize': 30}),
            dbc.Row(
                [
            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='graphQ', figure={}),md=8),
            html.P("1"),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="number", min=0, max=10, step=1),),
            html.P("2"),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="number", min=0, max=10, step=1)),
            ]),
            dbc.Row(
                [
            html.P("1"),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="number", min=0, max=10, step=1),),
            html.P("2"),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Input(type="number", min=0, max=10, step=1),)],
                align="end",
            )
            ])]))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def custom_input(paragraph_text, min_value=0, max_value=10, step=1):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.P(paragraph_text, style={"paddingRight": 10}),
            dbc.Input(type="number", min=min_value, max=max_value, step=step),
        ],
        style={"display": "flex"},
    )


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1("Query1", style={"textAlign": "center", "fontSize": 30}),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="graphQ", figure={}), md=8),
                dbc.Col(
                    children=[
                        dbc.Row(
                            [
                                dbc.Col(custom_input("1")),
                                dbc.Col(custom_input("2")),
                            ],
                            style={"paddingBottom": 30},
                        ),
                        dbc.Row(
                            [
                                dbc.Col(custom_input("1")),
                                dbc.Col(custom_input("2")),
                            ],
                            style={"paddingBottom": 30},
                        ),
                    ],
                    md=4,
                ),
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
```

I've abstracted your label / input component combination into a custom function to hopefully make the layout approach more clear and the code more reusable.

So my idea here is we only need one row with two columns. Where the first column consists of the entire graph.

The second column consists of two rows where each row contains two columns, each containing a custom input.

Comment: Thank you for ur explanation, the code works too :) !

Comment: Glad to help. By the way In addition to accepting an answer, you can also upvote answers that you've found helpful (Since, you've passed the upvote treshold of 15 reputation).

Comment: I have upvoted the answers, If you don't mind, I've got a qn, So I am working with decimal points, eg: 5.9. Can I just change `dbc.Input(type="number")` to `dbc.Input(type="float")`  ? or is there any other ways. thank you!

Comment: `dbc.Input` supports [the following control types](https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/blob/main/src/components/input/Input.js#L157). `dbc.Input` renders to a regular [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) so you could look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34057595/9098350) for ideas to apply in your situation. So that problem is not really a Dash problem, but more of a regular html input problem.

Comment: So viable solutions from looking at the stackoverflow post I shared earlier could be to do something using javascript or to use the `pattern` property and match valid input values using a regex.