# Decimal point on number input

Tags: javascript, input, decimal

Is it possible to add a decimal on a number input, as a user types?

I have the below input:

```
     <div class="form-control">
          <label for="bill">Bill</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="bill"
            name="bill"
            placeholder="0"
            maxlength="6"
          />
```

And I want it to look like the below as I type:
[image]

I've tried to set the input.value and wrap it in `formatter.format()`, using the below, but I get a parsing error. Because of the $ sign and it being a number input, I'm guessing.

```
let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
style: 'currency',
currency: 'USD', });
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow 2 decimal places in <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number)

Comment: I've already found and tried this and it doesn't work. The placeholder also needs to be 0 and the decimal to be added as the user types and adds more numbers. I've also removed the spin button, due to the design it needs to not have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to remove non digits, then add the decimal using string function.

```js
document.getElementById('bill').addEventListener('input', function(){
  if(this.value.length > 2){
    var val = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
    val = val.substr(0, val.length-2)+"."+val.substr(-2);
    this.value = val;
  }
});
```

```html
<input
  type="number"
  id="bill"
  name="bill"
  placeholder="0"
  maxlength="6"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there anyway to set it so the decimal is only placed in the input after the 3rd character?

Comment: @MattDavis I'd suggest you try an additional logic inside the callback to check for the length of the input value.

Comment: @MattDavis - Yes, I've updated the answer, but in the future please include all of your requirements in the question.