# Binding removes decimal separator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem with the Bind function in C# Asp.Net when working with decimal numbers. The decimal separator is being removed when the value is bound to the object.

For Example:

- Userinput: 7,5
- HTTP-Post (as reported by browser): 7.5
- Bindvalue: 75

Since this is likely to be relevant: I am from Germany and therefore having German as languagesetting in all applications. I have not made any changes in that regard within the code.

I have already tried different datatypes and HTML-Input-Types.
Any Idea on how to solve this?

Here is my code.

```
 public class ExampleClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public double Number { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Number" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Number" type ="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

The database has been created with entity framework migrations, which has resulted in a "float" type for the column in question.

Comment: What is stored in your DB?

Comment: Does your input allow decimal separator? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34057860/3279876

Comment: @PriyankPanchal the value without the decimal separator. In the example 75 would be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal binding in ASP.NET core is not culture invariant by default. The model binding depends on the server culture. You can do one of two things: create a custom model binder or (the way i solved this for my self) setting the decimal seperator for your application.
In the `Configure` method in the `Startup.cs` you can define and set your culture. So for you it would be something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

// Other configuring statements
}
```