# ASP Net Core decimal input with period turns into zero

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I am trying to create input control that will be pass decimal parameter "Weight".
Here's my .cshtml code:

```
<label asp-for="Input.Weight"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Weight" type="number" step="any" min="20" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Weight" class="text-danger"></span>
```

and below is my cs code:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Display(Name = "Waga [kg]")]
public decimal Weight { get; set; }
```

Every time when I try to put decimal value, it becomes zero (does not matter if I use comma or dot). When I write integer value, it works OK. I didn't find answer anywhere.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number)?

Comment: yes, I tried using regex pattern, using jQuery, step=".01" instead of 'any'

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved when I changed type 'decimal' to 'string' (ofc I added proper javascript to allow only decimals). But I still don't understand why my property Weight cannot be decimal...