# Is it possible to combine @bind-Value and @onchange in an input field?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to combine @bind-Value and @onchange in an input field in blazor. But when i do that i seems to get this error message `The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.`. I have found one solution for a work around like this  `<input class="form-control" type="number" @bind:event="oninput" @onchange="MethodIWantToTrigger" @bind="@MyProperty" />`
But the problem i get with this is that is not possible to write 0, ex i cant write 0.01 in the input field. Is there any other solution to make this combination?

Comment: For your second approach, possible duplicate: [Allow 2 decimal places in <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@bind` is just Razor syntactic sugar.  The Razor compiler builds a set of handlers in the compiled C# file.

Here are two examples of how you can code what I believe you want to do.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<input class="form-control mb-3" @bind:set="this.UpdateValue" @bind:get="_value" />

<input class="form-control mb-3" @bind="_value" @bind:after="DoSomeStuff" />

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    Value: @_value
</div>

@code{
    private decimal _value;

    private Task UpdateValue(decimal value)
    {
        _value = value;

        // Do you stuff

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task DoSomeStuff()
    {
        var myValue = _value;
        // Do you stuff

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your approach is quite proper. For the decimal situation, you can create your own custom component easily.

[Here is an example article for custom component to achive binding decimal numbers.](https://www.meziantou.net/bind-an-inputnumber-on-input-with-decimal-numbers-in-blazor.htm)

[Also please refer to Blazer University InputBase component article for better understanding](https://blazor-university.com/forms/descending-from-inputbase/)