# Decimal places when number format in excel

Tags: javascript, excel, js-xlsx

Now decimal place is 2, I want to change it depending on variable, is it possible?

```
cell.v = parseFloat(cell.v),
cell.t = 'n';
cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[2]; // 0.00 -> want to change to 0.000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript displaying a float to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163070/javascript-displaying-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: @RayonDabre it's not duplicate, it's about excel formatting, not just formatting number

Comment: If so, this is really not the way to ask the question..

Answer (score 2):

Just use [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
cell.z = Number(XLSX.SSF._table[2]).toFixed(3);//0.000
```

Comment: Value of `XLSX.SSF._table[2]` is `"0.00"`, so error is thrown `XLSX.SSF._table[2].toFixed is not a function`. I tried `cell.z = "0.000";` but it does not work.

Comment: First you need to convert it to the Number. Eg. Number("0.00").toFixed(3)

Comment: Have you tested with xlsx-js?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have. What happens?

Comment: Formatting is not applied at all. But thanks for trying to help

Comment: Bhojendra, what happens is that karaxuna has not correctly asked his question. I guessed the question and I replied.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a combination of `parseFloat()` and `toFixed()`:

```
cell.z = parseFloat(XLSX.SSF._table[2]).toFixed(3);
```

`ParseFloat()` is designed specifically to turn strings into numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from the comments, the OP wants to write a XLSX file using the `js-xlsx` library, with a number rendered with 3 decimals.

I achieve this as follows. I add the format code "0.000" to `XLSX.SSF._table`:

```
XLSX.SSF._table[164] = '0.000'
```

Then `cell.z = '0.000'` should work.

I don't know why the index 164. If there is another format, it goes to 165, then 166, etc.