# convert number to two decimal places and return as a number and not string

Tags: javascript

Given a variable

```
var str = 1;
```

convert  str to output 1.00 as a number and not string.

so the output should be 1.00 
and not "1.00"

what javascript operations should I use to do this?.

str.toFixed(2) returns a string and not a number so please..

Comment: Numbers are numbers.  They have no concept of a number of decimal places.  You can't do that.

Comment: Do you want to round to two decimal places?

Comment: yes, but the final output should be a number rather than a string

Comment: I guess @SLaks maybe right

Answer (score 2):

When you're talking about numbers, there *is* no difference between `1` and `1.00`. So, if it's a number, Javascript will treat them the same. If you want it as `1.00`, the only real way to do that is by creating a string of it with something like:

```
var nnn = 1;
var sss = nnn.toFixed(2));
```

The *presentation* of that number (either as a string or direct to output) may be under your control but the number itself is not (other than changing the value of course but, as already mentioned, there is no difference between the values `1`, `1.0` or `1e0`).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only has one kind of number: "number", which is a IEEE-754 Double Precision

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163070/javascript-displaying-a-float-to-2-decimal-places) to format to 2 decimal places.

Comment: the question is not more on formatting issue, is more about the results type to be a number and not string. which is not possible as answered above

Comment: Yes, the only kind of 'number' in js is "number" as specified by the IEEE-754 Double Precision specs.