# javascript rounding numbers to two decimal places

Tags: javascript

can someone let me know how I can achieve this type of rounding in javascript:

```
95.123 => 95.13
95.120 => 95.12
95.129 => 95.13
124.121 => 124.13
```

Thanks for the help.

A

Comment: How does `95.123` get “rounded” to `95.13` and `124.121` to `124.13`?

Comment: Do you want to round to the nearest or round up?

Comment: What have you tried already? Why are you rounding like this? Context is essential in answering your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are rounding only for display purposes, use `toFixed()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163070/javascript-displaying-a-float-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100`

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(95.123 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(95.120 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(95.129 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.ceil(124.121 * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: Thank you Karan, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way is to multiply by 100, round, and divide by 100.

```
let value = 95.123;
let rounded = Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
```

Another option is to use `Number.toFixed()` (be careful here, as `toFixed()` returns a string, not a number).

```
let value = 95.123;
let rounded = Number((value).toFixed(2));
```

A slightly more fancy approach would be to use exponential notation.

```
let value = 95.123;
let rounded = Number(Math.round(value+'e2')+'e-2');
```

This can be refactored into a helper function to handle different decimal values.

```
function roundToDec(value, decimals) {
  let posExp = 'e' + decimals;
  let negExp = 'e-' + decimals;
  return Number(Math.round(value + posExp) + negExp);
}

let value = 95.123;
let rounded = roundToDec(value, 2);
```