# Converting Float to 2 Decimal Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a `var` to a 2 decimal point number in Javascript, as follows:

```
var num1 = 9.7000000000

var newNum1= Math.floor(parseFloat(num1) * 100) / 100;
```

However, the output turns out to be `9.69`.

I appreciate any help or advice.

---

*Edit:* Thanks everyone, I have also tried `.toFixed(2)`.

However, I encountered issues when using it with arithmetic functions afterwards:

```
if (weight < newNum1)
```

---

*Resolved:* By adding a unary plus operator `+` as follows:

```
newNum1= +num1.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: `num1` is already a floating point number so `parseFloat` doesn't seem like it's doing anything.

Comment: use `.toFixed(2)` like `num1.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Also for why `9.7*100 = 969.9999999999` you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript displaying a float to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163070/javascript-displaying-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the value after`.toFixed(2)` to make it usable for arithmetic functions such as more than or less than?

Comment: This is an odd requirement. Getting two decimal points out of a number is just for presentation because a floating point  9.7000000000 is equal to 9.7 (the same way 0001 is equal to 1). If your actual requirement is to round your number to 2 decimal points (e.g. if you have something like 9.695... and want to get 9.70) that kind of changes the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed(2)` and the unary plus operator to convert the string back to a number.

```
const res = +num1.toFixed(2);//9.7
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried `.toFixed(2)`, but I encountered issue when using  for arithmetic functions afterwards, e.g. more than or less than the value

Comment: Did you use the unary plus operator like I have?

Comment: This is the shortest trick to do the job. But is twice as slow because it involves type conversion from number to string then back to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `toFixed` ?

The `toFixed()` method converts a number into a string, rounding to a specified number of decimals.

```js
var num1 = 9.7000000000

var newNum1= num1.toFixed(2)

console.log(newNum1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried `.toFixed(2)`, but I encountered issue when using  for arithmetic functions afterwards, e.g. more than or less than the value

Comment: Can you share the snippet?

Comment: I included a `unary` operator and it worked, thanks @xMayank

Answer (score 2):

You can use toFixed() method...,

```js
var num1 = 9.7000000000

var newNum1 = num1.toFixed(2);

console.log(newNum1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried `.toFixed(2)`, but I encountered issue when using  for arithmetic functions afterwards, e.g. more than or less than the value

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet:

```js
const round = (n, decimals = 0) => Number(`${Math.round(`${n}e${decimals}`)}e-${decimals}`);

console.log(round(9.7000000000, 2));
```

Ref: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/round

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "*actually*" modify the number to a 2 decimals (not only display formatting) then use the following solution. Here the number is actually changed internally to a new number.

If you use the **number.toFixed()** method you only show/display the number as a 2 decimal but the number is not changed. toFixed() is used for formatting.

```js
// Round to the required number of desimal places
// @input {number}   number to round
//        {decimals} number of decimal places
// @return {float} rounded number

function numberRoundDecimal(num, decimals) {
return Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,decimals))/Math.pow(10,decimals)
}

// ------- tests --------
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(9.7000000000,2))           // 9.7
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(-0.024641163062896567,3))  // -0.025
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(0.9993360575508052,3))     // 0.999
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(1.0020739645577939,3))     // 1.002
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(0.999,0))                  // 1
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(0.975,0))                  // 1
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(0.975,1))                  // 1
console.log(numberRoundDecimal(0.975,2))                  // 0.98
```