# Multiply numbers with more than 4 decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [round number in JavaScript to N decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/round-number-in-javascript-to-n-decimal-places)

This may be easy for you guys,

My question is:

How can I control a decimal places in a floating point value.

Ex.: My result is returning 0.365999999999999; but I need to show just 4 decimal numbers.

Check the demo: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ2z9/) (I accept any others ways to calculate that)

Thanks!

Comment: Entering `javascript round to 4 decimal places` in the search box on the top right of the page brought up [round number in JavaScript to N decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/round-number-in-javascript-to-n-decimal-places), among others. Please research before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.toFixed`

```
var number = 0.365999999999999;    
var rounded = number.toFixed(4);  // 0.3660
```

Comment: @ric_bfa: try 0.36544999 and see if the result suits you.

Comment: Also try `(0.9).toFixed(0)` in IE7 and [see if the result suits you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript/661757#661757).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){

   var number = parseFloat($("#number").text());
   var current = parseFloat($(this).val());

   var total = number*current;

   $("#result").val(total.toFixed(4));

});
```

Comment: I think you need to cast to a Float first

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#result").val(total.toFixed(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a nice `round` function, but it only does integers so you have to multiply it by 10000 then divide the rounded result by 10000

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/round.shtml

The `toFixed` function always rounds up, but `round` will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For proper rounding:

```
    function roundNumber(number, digits) {
        var multiple = Math.pow(10, digits);
        var rndedNum = Math.round(number * multiple) / multiple;
        return rndedNum;
    }
```

For rounding up:

```
number.toFixed(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){

   var number = $("#number").text();
   var current = $(this).val();

   var total = parseFloat(number*current).toFixed(2);

   $("#result").val(total);

});
```

**Cast the variable to a float** and then use the toFixed() method

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the link below you can import the number_format php function to javascript. The function has been helping me for years now.

Here is the function signature :

```
function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep)
```

http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481