# How to get Delphi Currency Type to Round like Excel all the time?

Tags: delphi, excel, format, currency, rounding

I'm trying to get Delphi to Round like Excel but I can't. Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 s : string;
 c : currency;
begin
 c := 54321.245;
 s := '';
 s := s + Format('Variable: %m',[c]);
 s := s + chr(13);
 s := s + Format('   Literal: %m',[54321.245]);
 ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

[image: Delphi Rounding]

I'm using a currency variable that is set to 54321.245 and when I format this variable it rounds using Bankers Rounding. However, when I format the same value as a literal it rounds the way that Excel rounds.

I was expecting this to round to **$54,321.25** whether it's formating a currency variable or a literal value. How can I make sure that Delphi rounds the same way as Excel every time?

**Edit**

```
The rounding I expect to see is as follows:  
54,321.245   = 54,321.25  
54,321.2449  = 54,321.24  
54,431.2499  = 54,421.25
```

I am only using literals to show the different ways Delphi rounds. I expect to use variables in the actual code.

***Note:***
If I change the variable from **currency** to **extended** it rounds correctly

**Edit #2**

Some have suggested that I do not have a clear understanding of my requirements, this is absolutely not true. I have a very clear understanding of my requirements, I'm obviously not doing a very good job of explaining them. The rounding method I want is two decimal places. When the deimal part has a thousandths value >= 0.005 I want it rounded to 0.01 the currency type offered by Delphi does not do this. I also tried this example using Microsoft SQL with a money datatype (which I assumed was the same as Delphi's currency) and SQL rounds it's money type the way I described.

- SQL Money >= 0.005 = 0.01
- Delphi Currency >= 0.005 := 0.00

**Edit #3**
Good Article: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html
Possible Solution: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html

**Edit #4**
Here is one of the solutions from the Embarcadero discussion

```
function RoundCurrency(const Value: Currency): Currency;
var
  V64: Int64 absolute Result;
  Decimals: Integer;
begin
  Result := Value;
  Decimals := V64 mod 100;
  Dec(V64, Decimals);
  case Decimals of
    -99 .. -50 : Dec(V64, 100);
    50 .. 99 : Inc(V64, 100);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure that Excel is 100% consistent in rounding throughout all its APIs and features?

Comment: @Warren - No I'm not 100% sure. I sell financial applications and I need to make sure that my numbers match what Excel puts out.

Comment: To properly answer this question, you really need to tell us what kind of rounding you expect.

Comment: Unless you carry exactly the same precision and do calculations in the same order you can't count on 100% matching any other program.  Furthermore, I don't think Excel supports fixed-precision data, Excel will sometimes get the financial calculations wrong.

Comment: You still haven't given any indication of what rounding method you want. Three examples does not a specification make. Until you have a clear understanding of your requirements, how can you hope to meet those requirements?

Comment: @Sertac - That is exactly what I was looking for. Make this an answer I you get my vote.

Comment: Also checkout workarrounds in other languages that may be applicable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/javascript-formatting-a-rounded-number-to-n-decimals/56632526#56632526

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for this:

```
function RoundTo2dp(Value: Currency): Currency;
begin
  Result := Trunc(Value*100+IfThen(Value>0, 0.5, -0.5))/100;
end;
```

Comment: As far as I've read so far, I can tell using the FPU when dealing with currency is not recommended. It can introduce hard to track rounding issues. There are solutions in the thread I linked that  avoid this or do it with great care.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz What are you driving at? Arithmetic in Currency makes use of FPU I think.

Comment: @Sertac - I read that thread plus Rudy's blog. David's solution is very good. It does not violate any of the conversion issues that were talked about.

Comment: @David - I'm not quite sure what I'm driving at... - Cape - I have not answered your question in the title anyway. If you can change the accept, I'll be more comfortable.

Comment: David, just to let you know... I'm totally *in love* with this func and I use it in my code :)

Comment: Note this will fail for some large numbers.  For Win-32:  147_573_952_589_676.4250.  For Win-64:  72_057_594_037.9450.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to make RTL to round the way you want. The way to affect the rounding in Delphi is to use [`SetRoundMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SetRoundMode) which [sets the FPU conrol word](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Floating-Point_Rounding_Issues#Control_Settings) for rounding, however, as far as I can tell, there's no FPU support for rounding the exact in-between to upwards (which is generally avoided because it generates a bias for higher values).

You have to implement your own rounding function. There's an extended discussion in [Delphi Rounding thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=70064) on Embarcadero forums, which includes several solutions.

Answer (score 1):

use function System.Math.SimpleRoundTo

Comment: Occam's Razor... I'll look into this one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Answer (score 0):

You can gain control on how delphi rounding numbers by :

```
uses Math;
...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
s : string;
c : currency;
begin
 SetRoundMode(rmNearest);

 c := 54321.245;
 s := '';
 s := s + Format('Variable: %m',[c]);
 s := s + chr(13);
 s := s + Format('   Literal: %m',[54321.245]);
 ShowMessage(s);
end;
```

Unfortunately, using rmNearest, Delphi decides the number 54321.245 is closer to 54321.24 than 54321.25

Comment: That's not exactly true. If you change the value of c := 54321.244 it formats as $54,321.45 and it should be $54,321.44 (I wish it were that simple). It appears that using an extended type instead of currency is the work around for this.

Comment: Don't appologize, we are all learning. It appears that the currency type does not round or format like the extended type. I just looked at several of the financial functions inside Delphis's Math unit and not one of them uses a currency type. They all use the extended type. So, if it works for Delphi's Math unit it works for me. :-)

Comment: 54321.245 is not exactly representable in floating point, so once again the example in this answer turn out to illustrate issues of representability and not issues of rounding. @Cape Financial calculations are no good with binary floating point. You really need to use decimal arithmetic. The .net decimal type is effective. It's rather a shame that Delphi is so lame in this area.