# Formatting String on Client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, string, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: formatting a rounded number to N decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/javascript-formatting-a-rounded-number-to-n-decimals)

I'm modifying a label text using JavaScript

I need to format that label text in the form (ex: 45.00). 
Now it is being displayed as (45)

How can I achieve this from client side

To accomplish this from server side, I'm doing - lb.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", rondedamount);

I need this from client side (Inside Label) or from JavaScript.

Comment: I guess you know how to get and set element value use javascript, than with the function metioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format, it should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work for you :

```
var num = 45;
formated_num = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(formated_num);
```

The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.
where the toPrecision, Returns a string representing a Number object in fixed-point or exponential notation rounded to precision significant digits.

Comment: i just edited my answer check now

Comment: Precision means the no of digits are fixed. But Fixed means the no of decimal digits are fixed

Comment: please post your previous answer also with description. It might be helpful to others also

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 45;
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```