# Change Numbers ro Strings and round them correctly JS

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I fetch around 1000 different numbers from a CMS to display them in my frontend. I want to display anything above 1000 as 1k and so on. There are only full numbers fetched and no decimals.
Few examples: `1200 = 1.2k, 1209 = 1.2k, 18094 = 18.1k  999 = 999`

So in the first place i have to check every number if it has more than 3 digits, if so it should round correctly and after it append a "k" to the number (now string in this case).
The first step is clear to me but i struggle a bit with the correct rounding. The solution should also be as most cost efficient as possible. The solution needs to be in JS.

Maybe someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi You can try http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: formatting a rounded number to N decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/javascript-formatting-a-rounded-number-to-n-decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `Number`, if > 1000 divide by 1000 and use `Number.toFixed` to display

```js
["22", "13421"].forEach( n => console.log(+n > 1000 ? `${(+n/1000).toFixed(1)}k` : n) );
```

Answer (score 1):

For rounding, after dividing, use `toFixed` to take only one digit after `.`

- `num = (num/1000).toFixed(1);`

Add the details code here,

```js
//test run data
let nums = [10,10,100,1000,2000,2220];
//just for printing
let numString = '';
//you can store in another or ...

nums.forEach(converter);

function converter(num){
  if(num >= 1000){
    num = (num/1000).toFixed(1);
    numString = num+ 'k';
  }else{
    numString = num+'';
  }
  console.log(numString);
}
```