# How to add undefined element to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, undefined

It's simple, i want to add an undefined element to an array, lets say i have an array Punkt and i have `punkt[0] = x: 15, y:"16s"`    . As i know for ex. the element will have 4 punkt in total i want to add an undefined element to `punkt[3]`, so that also the others `punkt[1]` and `punkt[2]` will become `undefined`.
I need this because somewhere later in my code i do a check for `undefined`, and throw an error based on this.

Racks is an object that contains an array of objects Punkt

```
punkt[0] = {
x: 5,
y: "16s" }
```

What i tried:

```
racks[trimdevID].punkt[$('#posTable tr:last td:first').text()] = undefined;
```

Comment: Well what happens when you try that? Do you get an error?  What's the value of that jQuery `.text()` expression?

Comment: Why are you prefilling the array? If you try to access `punkt[1]` it will return `undefined`. What benefit is there of putting `undefined` in there?

Comment: Are you simply trying to empty your array? You shouldn't really ever want to make an array index undefined, you should simply remove that particular index using splice.

Comment: Nothing happens at the moment :( 
the .text will return a value that is a number, possibly in a string, i will try casting that

Comment: *"i want to add an `undefined` element to `punkt[3]`, so that also the others `punkt[1]` and `punkt[2]` will become `undefined`"* Why? The default value is `undefined`. Adding `punkt[3]` doesn't really do anything for you. It certainly does nothing to change `punkt[1]` and `punkt[2]`.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, if you want your Array to show a `.length` of `4`, then setting `punkt[3]` would do that, but you can also just do  it manually. `punkt.length = 4;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use the push() routine (see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp). In your example, that would look something like:

```
// push two undefined elements:
racks[trimdevID].punkt.push(undefined)
racks[trimdevID].punkt.push(undefined)
```

That assumes that you already have exactly two elements in the array and you want exactly four elements. The more generic version of this is:

```
var newLength = 4;
for (var idx = racks[trimdevID].punkt.length; idx <= newLength; idx++)
{
   racks[trimdevID].punkt.push(undefined);
}
```

I believe other similar stack questions also have the same answer. You might look at this question for more examples ([How to initialize an array's length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/proper-way-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript))

Comment: Thanks for the link, initializing array lenght also helps for me

Answer (score 2):

`undefined` is [built in property of the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2Fundefined) and it's indeed what you need, so such code for example [*is* working](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Xg9/):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(undefined);
alert(typeof arr[0]);
```

This means your problem is elsewhere, from quick look it's because you're using non integer index. Try this instead and it should work:

```
var index = parseInt($('#posTable tr:last td:first').text(), 10);
if (!isNaN(index))
    racks[trimdevID].punkt[index] = undefined;
```

Comment: if(changingPos<parseInt($('#posTable tr:last td:first').text()))
       {
       racks[trimdevID].punkt[parseInt($('#posTable tr:last td:first').text())] = undefined;
       }

Comment: `undefined` isn't a keyword.

Comment: @BlueSkies wrong semantics... not a keyword and you can declare local variable with same name but it's still what I meant. Semantics fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try **[.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** in array

```
yourArray.push(undefined)
i = 0; //Position Of Undefined
console.log(typeof yourArray[i])
```