# Javascript TypedArray performance

Tags: javascript, performance, typed-arrays

Why are TypedArrays not as fast as regular arrays? I want to store some precalculated integer values, and I need the access to the array to be as fast as it can be.

http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed-2/2

Preparation code:

```
 Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
   var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(0x10000);
   var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
   var arr = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i) {
     Uint32[i] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
     arr[i] = Uint32[i];
   }
   var sum = 0;
 };
```

Test 1:

```
sum = arr[(Math.random() * 0x10000) | 0];
```

Test 2:

```
sum = Uint32[(Math.random() * 0x10000) | 0];
```

[image]

PS: May be my perf tests are invalid feel free to correct me.

Comment: Did you delete the jsperf tests? I can't access them any more

Comment: No, i've not removed it. This is strange.

Comment: Very, very strange that they would have disappeared like that! All of them... Particularly strange in light of [this FAQ entry](http://jsperf.com/faq#test-availability). I've searched in case the URL changed or something, and...nothing. I can find other tests of array performance, but not Sukhanov's and mine. I've raised an [issue for it](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com/issues/197). Of course, it probably wouldn't hurt if more of us [donated to jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/faq#donate) (and I just did...for the first time *ducks head*).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(0x10000);
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
```

is not the same thing as:

```
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(0x10000);
```

not because of the new `ArrayBuffer` (you always get an array buffer: see `Uint32.buffer` in both cases) but because of the length parameter: with `ArrayBuffer` you have 1 byte per element, with `Uint32Array` you have 4 bytes per element.

So, in the first case (and in your code), `Uint32.length = 0x1000/4` and your loops are out of bounds 3 out of 4 times. But sadly you will never get errors, only poor performances.

Using `new ArrayBuffer`, you have to declare Uint32 like this:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(0x10000 * 4);
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);
```

See [jsperf with (0x10000)](http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed3) and [jsperf with (0x10000 * 4)](http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed3/2).

Comment: It's a shame that people accept answers basing on the content size, but not on correctness.

Comment: @MorrisLiang, that's what I thought as well, but then I realised this answer was posted over half a year after the question.

Comment: @MorrisLiang: Note that my answer *always* used `new Uint32Array(0x10000)` to compare apples with apples length-wise, and still revealed speed differences. But I didn't call out the difference the way radsoc did above.

Answer (score 57):

Modern engines will use true arrays behind the scenes even if you use `Array` if they think they can, falling back on property map "arrays" if you do something that makes them think they can't use a true array.

Also note that as [radsoc points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275664/157247), `var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(0x10000)` then `var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(buffer)` produces a Uint32 array whose size is 0x4000 (0x10000 / 4), not 0x10000, because the value you give `ArrayBuffer` is in bytes, but of course there are four bytes per Uint32Array entry. All of the below uses `new Uint32Array(0x10000)` instead *(and always did, even prior to this edit)* to compare apples with apples.

So let's start there, with `new Uint32Array(0x10000)`: <s>http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed-2/11</s> *(sadly, JSPerf has lost this test and its results, and is now offline entirely)*

[image: graph showing roughly equivalent performance]

That suggests that because you're filling the array in a simple, predictable way, a modern engine continues to use a true array (with the performance benefits thereof) under the covers rather than shifting over. We see basically the same performance for both. The difference in speed could relate to type conversion taking the `Uint32` value and assigning it to `sum` as a `number` (though I'm surprised if that type conversion isn't deferred...).

Add some chaos, though:

```
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(0x10000);
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0x10000 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  Uint32[Math.random() * 0x10000 | 0] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
  arr[Math.random() * 0x10000 | 0] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
}
var sum = 0;
```

...so that the engine has to fall back on old-fashioned property map "arrays," and you see that typed arrays markedly outperform the old-fashioned kind: <s>http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed-2/3</s> *(sadly, JSPerf has lost this test and its results)*

[image: bar graph showing marked performance improvement for typed arrays]

Clever, these JavaScript engine engineers...

The specific thing you do with the non-array nature of the `Array` array matters, though; consider:

```
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(0x10000);
var arr = [];
arr.foo = "bar";                            // <== Non-element property
for (var i = 0; i < 0x10000; ++i) {
  Uint32[i] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
  arr[i] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
}
var sum = 0;
```

That's still filling the array predictably, but we add a non-element property (`foo`) to it. <s>http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed-2/4</s> *(sadly, JSPerf has lost this test and its results)* Apparently, engines are quite clever, and keep that non-element property off to the side while continuing to use a true array for the element properties:

[image: bar graph showing performance improvement for standard arrays when <code>Array</code> array gets non-element property]

I'm at a bit of a loss to explain why standard arrays should get *faster* there compared to our first test above. Measurement error? Vagaries in `Math.random`? But we're still pretty sure the array-specific data in the `Array` is still a true array.

Whereas if we do the same thing but fill in reverse order:

```
var Uint32 = new Uint32Array(0x10000);
var arr = [];
arr.foo = "bar";                            // <== Non-element property
for (var i = 0x10000 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {    // <== Reverse order
  Uint32[i] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
  arr[i] = (Math.random() * 0x100000000) | 0;
}
var sum = 0;
```

...we get back to typed arrays winning out — except on IE11: <s>http://jsperf.com/array-access-speed-2/9</s> *(sadly, JSPerf has lost this test and its results)*

[image: graph showing typed arrays winning except on IE11]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Things gets more complicated in real-use case, where continous allocation/disallocations of various objects/arrays leads to memory fragmentation, and processing time explodes if memory is not pre-allocated. In real life Typed Array will cost less since they're pre-allocated (Rq : js Arrays might be preallocated also...)

Comment: Writing pre-calced int32 values to typed array is fast. The array does not contain holes (yeah, holes are fast but…). The array is preallocated. So creating and initialization typed array is fast. But when you try to read from Uint32Array the value should be converted to double (see my answer below). You should use Int32Array (on x64) or Int16Array (on x86) (see my answer below again).

Answer (score 1):

In your case the reason of bad performance is you try to read outside the array when using Uint32Array because of bug with array length.

But if it wouldn't be the real reason then:

Try to use Int32Array instead of Uint32Array. I think in V8 variables cannot have uint32 type but can have int32 / double / pointer. So when you assign uint32 type to variable it will be converted to slower double.

If you use 32-bit version of V8 then variables can have int31 / double / pointer type. So int32 will be converted into double too. But if you use usual array and all values are int31 then conversion is not needed so usual array can be faster.

Also using int16 can require some conversions to get int32 (because of sign and ones' complement).
Uint16 will not require conversion because V8 can just add zeros in the left.

PS. You may be interested pointers and int31 (or int32 on x64) are the same things in V8. This also means that int32 will require 8 bytes on x64. Also this is reason why there's no int32 type on x86: because if we would used all 32 bits for storing integer we wouldn't have any space to save pointers anymore.