# Array of boolean values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean, bit-manipulation

In JavaScript, is there a way to do this in a more efficient way?

I need to create an array of boolean values, change them and check them individually and at random.

The goal is better performance.
Maybe manipulating bits.

Right now I use something like this:

```
var boolean = [];

var length = 100; // set a random number of values
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) boolean[i] = false; // or true

boolean[n] = true; // change some of the values randomly
if (boolean[n]) { /* something */ } // check some of the values randomly
```

Comment: Better performance of which part? Creating the array? Filling it with `false`? Updating it later?

Comment: Sorry, too accustomed to notifications.
The checking of the values is most important to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are three parts to this:

1. Creating the array

   Somewhat counter-intuitively, what you're doing is already just fine even though standard JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), because the way you're creating and filling in the array, a modern engine will use a true array behind the scenes. (See [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24855023/157247) for more on that, including performance tests.) So even on engines that have true arrays like `Uint8Array`, what you're doing is fine. But see point #2 below.
2. Filling it with falsey values

   As there are only 100 entries, it just doesn't matter how you do this, unless you're creating and filling in the array repeatedly in a tight loop. If you are, then a `Uint8Array` should win, because `new Uint8Array(100)` is pre-filled with zeroes and you don't have to fill it in at all.
3. Accessing the array's entries

   You don't really have much choice there, you do it the way you're doing it. Provided you create the array the way you are or you use a `Uint8Array`, that's probably as fast as it's going to get.

I find http://jsperf.com helpful for comparing approaches to things and seeing how they turn out on real-world JavaScript engines. For instance, here's a test case suggesting that a `Uint8Array` will offer a *slight* advantage on SpiderMonkey (Firefox's engine), be about the same on V8 (Chrome's engine), and *very slightly* slower on JScript (IE11's engine):

Standard array:

```
var a, n, dead;

// Creation
a = [];

// Filling
for (n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
    a[n] = false;
}

// Accessing randomly 5,000 times
dead = 1;
for (n = 0; n < 5000; ++n) {
    a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)] = true;
    if (a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]) {
        ++dead; // Just to be doing something
    }
}

// Make sure engine knows we're using the result
if (dead === 0) { throw "Error in test"; }
```

`Uint8Array`:

```
var a, n, dead;

// Creation
a = new Uint8Array(100);

// Filling
// None!

// Accessing randomly 5,000 times
dead = 1;
for (n = 0; n < 5000; ++n) {
    a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)] = 1;
    if (a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]) {
        ++dead; // Just to be doing something
    }
}

// Make sure engine knows we're using the result
if (dead === 0) { throw "Error in test"; }
```

Results on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty cool explanation, I didn't know, that you have access to something as low-level as an actual array in js.

Comment: Thanks. Not as much of an improvement as I hoped. I guess standard arrays are pretty optimized.

Comment: @CarlosGil: Only if you play nice with them. :-) Otherwise, with some engines, you fall back into dictionary mode where array indexes are nothing more than property names (see [the answer linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24855023/157247) for ways that can happen).

Answer (score 1):

may be this way

```
var length = 100,
    item,
    arr = (Array(length)).fill(1),
    getRandBool = function() { return Math.random(Date()) * 10 > 6; },
    getRandIdx = function() { return (Math.random(Date()) * (length + 1))|0; };

arr.forEach(function(val, idx) { arr[idx]= getRandBool(); });

arr[getRandIdx()] = getRandBool();


if(item = arr[getRandIdx()]) { console.log(item) }
```