# Does the shorter comprehension syntax require a range as a source?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, list-comprehension

I would like to create an array initialized to all zeros, with the same length as another array. I've heard that `new Array(baz.length)` isn't recommended because the array constructor is ambiguous. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852052/2216771)) No matter, for CoffeeScript has beautiful array comprehensions! For example, this works:

```
foo = (0 for i in baz)
```

This is readable and concise, and I'm happy. (Hooray CoffeeScript!) But I really don't need the current iteration value in this case. I just need an element for each element in baz. The CoffeeScript [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) states

> If you don't need the current iteration value you may omit it:
>
> `browser.closeCurrentTab() for [0...count]`

So I should be able to say

```
foo = (0 for baz)
```

but I get an `unexpected )` error in the compiler there. Oddly, a more complex version does work:

```
foo = (0 for [0...(baz.length)])
```

Does this rule from the docs only apply to comprehensions that have a range as a source? Is there a cleaner option for this task?

Comment: I personally __hate__ this style of _cute, magical_ code. At first pass, I have no idea what your code is supposed to do. On the other hand, the _deliberate and obvious_ version, `foo = [];
baz.forEach -> foo.push 0` is crystal clear, even if you maintain the strict paren-phobia encouraged by CS fans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually think that `new Array baz.length` is the cleaest way to write it.  The ambiguity cannot occur as baz.length will always be a number.

I tend to agree with you though that the documentation implies that `0 for baz` should work.  Possibly worth a bug report?