# Dynamic Array of objects for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, object

This is what i have so far. Basically every time i make a new Item object i need it to create a specific number of another object called Sensor. I've tried a few other methods and none seem to way the work that i need.

```
function Item (id,number,operator,numOfSensors){
    this.id = id;
    this.number = number;
    this.operator = operator;
    this.numOfSensors = numOfSensors;
    var sensor = new Sensor[numOfSensors];

}

var Sensor = {
    timeStamp:[],

    itemPassed: function(){
        timeStamp.push(Date.now());
    }

}
```

Thanks so much for any help :) i'm a bit new to js 
EDIT:

Hey guys! Thanks for the help. Basically my issue is neatly making an array of Objects. In the item object i want to make a [numOfSensors] amount of the Sensor object. I cant seem to find a way to do that. SO i guess my question is how would i go about creating an array of objects with a set number of elements?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Hard grasping exactly what you want. It seems you may have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the help. Basically my issue is neatly making an array of Objects. In the item object i want to make a [numOfSensors] amount of the Sensor object. I cant seem to find a way to do that. SO i guess my question is how would i go about creating an array of objects with a set number of elements?

Comment: @ArinYaldizciyan usually "array of objects" refers to a structure like this: `[ {}, {}, {} ]` but I'm not following what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, ill try to explain better. Basically when i make a new Item object. You'll notice i have a line within the item object that says var sensor = new Sensor[3]; i want the Item object to make 3 New sensor objects. The thing is the way i've written it that doesnt seem to work. How would you guys create an array of objects? Sorry if that's not a good way of explaining it

Comment: You really have to learn basics. You're talking about `Item` object, but it's a function, then you're using `Sensor` object as it was a function ... Please add all the relevant information from comments to your question, nobody is going to dig it out from a long comment thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when you really want to call `itemPassed()` and whether this is not rather a function of `Item`, but here is some code that might get you get started:

```js
var Item = function (id, number, operator, numOfSensors) {
    this.id = id;
    this.number = number;
    this.operator = operator;
    this.numOfSensors = numOfSensors;
    var sensorArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<numOfSensors; i++) {
        sensorArray.push(new Sensor());
    }
}

var Sensor = function() {
    this.timeStamps = [];
}

Sensor.prototype.itemPassed = function(){
    this.timeStamps.push(Date.now());
}
```

See:

- [How to initialize an array's length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/proper-way-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript)
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/prototypes-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know--net-24949