# functional loop given a number instead of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a number 18, instead of an array, in hand.

What is the best way to create a *functional* loop in JS given a number X instead of array of X elements?

I can do this:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(){

));
```

but if I have the number 3

I can do

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

}
```

but I want that loop to be functional instead

Comment: We have moved on past functional-style and are now using generators. Back to the `for` statement!

Comment: @torazaburo , i am not sure if he asked the same question as you have marked it duplicate for i think he just wants to iterate x number times without creating an array or using for loop. not sure maybe.

Comment: something like this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jaxoyiweva/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Iterating *n* times in a "functional way" is the same, for all practical purposes, as creating an array of n numbers and then using some iterating-type function like `map` or `forEach` on the result, so yes, I would say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this. An equivalent to:

```js
[1,2,3].forEach(function(){ ... ));
```

Is

```js
var limit = n;
while (--limit) {(  // Note: 0 is falsy
    function(){ ... }
)(limit);}
```

Or if you really want to use an array structure, the following will do:

```js
new Array(limit).fill(0).forEach(function(){...});
```

You might be interested in [*Myth of the Day: Functional Programmers Don't Use Loops*](https://two-wrongs.com/myth-of-the-day-functional-programmers-dont-use-loops).

Comment: Note, `.fill` is new to ES6 so might not be supported on all modern browsers just yet.

Comment: because I need to pass the value of the index  to the function

Comment: I think it's limit-- not --limit

Comment: @AlexanderMills—yes, `limit--`. The OP makes no use of the index, but if that's required, then *limit* counts down and `n - limit` counts up.

Comment: well a for-loop in general will trigger functional programmers b/c theres pretty much always side effects unless you are just doing fire and forget i/o…but sure map/filter are ok?

Comment: @AlexanderMills—sure, just use whatever suits. I don't get hung up on paradigms and just use whatever seems appropriate. To me, creating an array of *x* elements just to loop *x* times to do something entirely unrelated is less appealing than a *for/do/while* loop of *x* iterations. As for unintended side effects, given that ECMAScript has block scope, it's really not an issue IMHO. :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you have a number and you want to create a loop then you can use the number in limiter condition in the for loop.

`for(var i = 0; i < number; i++)`

**Edit 1:** you can use `foreach` on arrays only, in that case since you have a number already you can create a array of that length and then use the foreach on it.

`var foo = new Array(number).fill(0);`

`foo.foreach()`

Also another option is

`var N = 18;`

`Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number)`

> result [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]

Many more options available in this thread [Create a JavaScript array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n)

Comment: yes, but I was looking for a *functional* for loop, etc :)

Comment: @AlexMills, meaning a `forEach` style call?

Comment: @AlexMills what do you mean by functional for loop?? I never heard that before.. May be some links to it will help

Comment: yes, forEach, but with a number

Comment: `Array.apply(null, Array(number)).map(function () {}).forEach(...)` is about the closest you can get.

Comment: ok I made some edits, thanks Matt, do you think you could add that as an answer?

Comment: @Reddy. Just to note, an Array with a constructor length is not iterable, hence the `.Apply` approach.

Comment: Actually, `new Array(5).forEach` will **not** do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/proper-way-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript), you can "functionally" iterate over a linear sequence relatively easily using:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(number)).map(function () {}).forEach(...)
```

Not sure what advantage this gives you versus a regular `for`-loop with an index, though it is a neat trick.

Comment: I think the advantage is that it's way more code than `while(i--)...` ;-)

Comment: To be fair, the `while(i--)` is a reversed linear sequence :)

Comment: If the index matters (and it doesn't in the OP) then `while (++i < limit) ...` or `do ... while(i++ < limit)` and so on.

Comment: That's fair. I think we're a little OT at this point.

Comment: index does matter in OP :)