# undefined parameter in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am receiving a type error stating that the array testA[i] is undefined whenever I add an input into the html page. I have the array set and i'm trying to add the value of currency to the array using the push method to add to the second part of the array i.e([0][currency])

```
function Test() {

var testA = [];
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.currency = prompt("Please enter a 3-letter currency abbreviation", "");
        testA[i].push(currency);
        }
}
var index = new Test();
```

[image]

any help as to why the array is undefined would be appreciated.

Note: I have now tried both testA.push(currency) and testA[i] = this.currency, and I still get the same error as before.

Note: the final version should have it loop through 4 different questions asked and each time adding these into an array. At the end of the loop a new variant of the array should be made and the new set of data entered will be added to it. something like
    
     `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     testA[i] = i;
     for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     this.currency = prompt("Please enter a 3-letter currency abbreviation", "");
     testA[i][j] = this.currency;
     } 
     }`

but at this point in time I'm just trying to get it to work.

Comment: forgot to mention, this needs to loop for 4 different parts. hence I need the currency value to be at the index. testA[i][0]<- here. then once the loop hits the end, i goes up by 1 and it asks the question again. after 4 times I should have 
testA[0][currency]
testA[1][currency]
testA[2][currency]
testA[3][currency]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use the `push` method on a index. You use it on the array itself.

Replace this

```
testA[i].push(currency);
```

With this

```
testA.push(currency);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform push operation on the array directly.

```
testA.push(currency);
```

By executing `testA[index]` you will receive hold value. In JS it will always return `undefined`, if index is greater than array length.

Because your array is empty as the beginning, you are always receiving `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different implementation.

Either you use direct assignation.

```
var testA = new Array(4);

for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    this.currency = prompt('...', '');

    testA[i] = this.currency;
}
```

---

Either you push new values into the array.

```
var testA = [];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    this.currency = prompt('...', '');

    testA.push(this.currency);
}
```

**You should use the second one, which is the most simple** [soluce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

```
testA[i] = this.currency OR testA.push(this.currency)
```

Use Modified function below

```
function Test() {
       var testA = [];
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    this.currency = prompt("Please enter a 3-letter currency abbreviation", "");
                    testA[i] = this.currency; // use this.currency here if you 
                    }
            console.log(testA);
            }

var index = new Test();
```