# convert number to array in javascript | typescript for angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a number 10 how to convert to this to number array in java script.
answer should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

OR How to convert number(10) to number of items in array in javascript

Comment: Posible duplicated: [How to initialize an array's length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript)

Comment: One problem with marking duplicates, the marked duplicate was asked back in 2010,.  Things have moved on, and a nice feature of filling arrays these days would be with an iterator.  The marked duplicate has this, but it's buried deep within all the other answers, one had 7 up-votes & the other had 1, until I up-voted them.  Might take a while before those get near the top :)  Doing something like `Array.from(numRange(1, 10))` in the long run just looks nice..

Answer (score 3):

A simple for loop will easily accomplish this task.

```js
var number = 10;
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) arr.push(i+1);

console.log(arr)
```

You can also use:

`Array.from(new Array(number), (x,i) => i+1)`

```js
var number = 10;

var arr = Array.from(new Array(number), (x,i) => i+1)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Might be the same people who marked as duplicate.  Technically it's a duplicate, but from 2010, it might have still be a good idea to keep this one open so that modern ways of doing this can be shown.  Especially using generators, as that's really hidden inside the dupe.  ps. I'll up-vote, as your correct is wrong when they do this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a variable `let a` which implies your last number in array and at the same time number of elements in array.

```
let a = 10;
```

Now initialize an array which you will populate with numbers

```
let arr = [];
```

Now do a for loop and push the numbers in the array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < a; i++)
    arr.push(i+1);
```

This will populate array `arr` with numbers from 1 to 10.