# Typescript create null array of specified length

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am using splice to add elements to an array at specified index.However In order to to do so I have to create a null array to add the elements at particular index.

If I use an empty array,the elements are not being pushed at specific instance.Right now i'm creating an empty array and then pushing null to that array.I want to know if I can achieve this with any other way.

This is what I'm doing:

```
arr:any[];
for(let i=0;i<userDefinedLength;i++)
{
    arr.push(null);
}
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array's length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript)

Comment: Try doing `new Array(userDefinedLength).fill(null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arr = new Array(userDefinedLength).fill(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `fill`:

```
arr: any[] = new Array(userDefinedLength).fill(null);
```

You can't use `null[]` unless you're just using the array as a placeholder:

```
arr: null[] = new Array(userDefinedLength).fill(null);
```