# Vue: how to set props to an array range?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a grid created for videos.  It makes a call to an api to return back videos.  I have a state `isFetching` that is set to true when the page loads and tries to retrieve the list from the API.  After the videos are retrieved, `isFetching` is set to `false` and the data is stored as `videoList`.

I am using a grid with a placeholder component for each item if the API takes a while to fetch.  The `VideoGrid` expects a `items` because inside of it, it iterates through it.  I want to have 16 grid items but I don't want to have to do `:items=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`.  I tried `:items="[new Array(16).keys()]` but that seems to create a nested array.  Is there a way to accomplish this without having to write it out like that?

**Main.vue**

```
<VideoGrid v-if="isFetching && !videoList" :items="[1,2,3,4,5,6]">
  <template>
    <ItemPlaceholder />
  </template>
</VideoGrid>

<VideoGrid v-else :items="videoList">
  <template v-slot="slotProps>
    <VideoComponent :title="slotProps.title" />
  </template>
</VideoGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to remove the brackets from your `items` declaration like so:

```
<VideoGrid v-if="isFetching && !videoList" :items="Array(16).fill(1)">
  <template>
    <ItemPlaceholder />
  </template>
</VideoGrid>

<VideoGrid v-else :items="videoList">
  <template v-slot="slotProps>
    <VideoComponent :title="slotProps.title" />
  </template>
</VideoGrid>
```

`Array(16).fill(1)` will create an array with 16 number 1's. If you want to have incrementing values in your array you can use `Array.from({length: 16}, (v, i) => i)` or see [How to initialize an array's length in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript?rq=1).