# chunk array into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to chunk my array into 3 using this code

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
let chunk;

while (a.length > 0) {
  chunk = a.splice(0, 3);
  console.log(chunk);
}
```

but how can I get a result something like these

```
var array1 = ["a", "d", "g"];
var array2 = ["b", "e"];
var array3 = ["c", "f"];
```

Comment: the first chunk must always have three items?  I doesnt matter if the array have 10 , 20 or more items?

Comment: @jabaa sorry for the confusion. Yes, I want to split it into 3 arrays, but the result must not be something like this one array1 = ["a", "b", "c", ...], please see above for the sample result. thank you

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes, it doesn't matter if the array has more than 3 or more elements, but the pattern or result must be something in the sample above. thank you

Comment: Iterate over `a` and put the first element into `array1`, the second element into `array2`, the third element into `array3`, ... The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
const numberOfArrays = 3;
let arrays = Array.apply(null, Array(numberOfArrays)).map(it=>[])
a.forEach((value,i)=>{
  arrays[(i%numberOfArrays)].push(value);
})
console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `.map(it=>[])` do, please?

Comment: Array(numberOfArrays) create array with 3 values 
map(it=>[]) replace every element with empty array 
there is a great explanation i recommend  you the read here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28599347/4267015

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried with `Array(3).fill([]);` and got same `[[],[],[]]`. Afterwards i run your foreach: `a.forEach((value,i)=>{
  arrays[(i%3)].push(value);
})` But i got completly wrong result. I dont understand it.

Comment: `a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

chunk = Array(3).fill([]);

a.forEach((value,i) => {  
  chunk[(i%3)].push(value);
})
console.log(chunk)
` full code for testing

Comment: from msdn`Value to fill the array with. (Note all elements in the array will be this exact value.)` arrays and object are copied by ref in js  all the elements in chunks  as same ref to the array you pass to fill function,  with map each cluser create new array

Comment: Okay. Thank you for explanation. To be honest, I haven't quite understood it yet, but I can guess what it means. ;-) Merci

Comment: what means `msdn Value`?

Comment: run this example then everything make more sense 

a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
const arr = ["moshe"]
chunk = Array(3).fill(arr);
a.forEach((value, i) => { chunk[(i % 3)].push(value); })
arr.push("x")
console.log(chunk)

Comment: msdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243548/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-naor-tedgi).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `a` and put the first element into `array1`, the second element into `array2`, the third element into `array3`, ...

```js
const a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

const [array1, array2, array3] = a.reduce((acc, el, idx) => {
  acc[idx % 3].push(el);
  return acc;
}, [[], [], []]);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: @jabba this is also a good solution. Thank you!