# Why is splice() not returning a value

Tags: javascript

I am wondering and this may be a stupid question why `splice` is giving me different results for apparently same situation.

one is using `[]` and the other one is using `Array` constructor

I've checked a bit on internet and apparently it may be about `sparse` values but maybe not. One thing though on one of my project I've used the second case and after inspecting the array, it looks like the index doesn't start from 0 but where the array was `spliced`  any ideas?

```js
const arr = new Array(3)

arr.push( 1 );
arr.push( 2 );
arr.push( 3 );

arr.splice( 0, 2 );

console.log( arr[ 0 ] );
```

```js
const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

arr.splice( 0, 2 );

console.log( arr[ 0 ] );
```

Comment: Not sure I get your title: splice() is returning a value, but you're not capturing the result of splice() in a variable? Also don't use the Array() constructor. There is no such thing as a "fixed length array" in JS, only "arrays that had their length property explicit set to a lie", so you're adding elements to an array that thinks its first three elements already exist =)

Comment: `for apparently same situation.` Its not. `console.log` your arrays, they are entirely different.

Comment: In your first example, you generate an array of `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize an array's length in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852017/how-to-initialize-an-arrays-length-in-javascript)

Comment: @miken32 this was a stupid mistake from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating array with new Array(3) constructor, your array already have three empty slots and every time you push something, you push it not to index 0, but to index 3. In the end you have

```
Array(6) [ <3 empty slots>, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

So arr[0] is actually empty slot.
You need to set your values instead of pushing

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Case 1:

When you create an array using `const arr = new Array(3);`, you're creating an array object with a length of 3, where each value is undefined. Adding three values with `arr.push(1), arr.push(2), and arr.push(3)` would result in an array like this: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, 1, 2, 3]`

#### Case 2:

You start with an array containing `[1, 2, 3]`. Using `arr.splice(0, 2)` removes the first two elements `[1, 2]`, leaving only `[3]`. When you log `arr[0]`, it shows 3, as it is now the first and only element in the array.

Ref: [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: *'where each value is undefined'* this is not technically accurate, it has three empty slots.