# Convert numerical value to a string filled with a character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, integer, return

The best way to explain this is with examples.

Let's say I have the integer 5. I plug it into a function, and it would return the space character (" ") 5 times in a single variable, like "     ".

I have the integer 3. I plug it into a function, and the output would be "   " (3 spaces).

Hopefully you get the point. What is the best way to accomplish this. I feel like there is a really simple way to do this in JavaScript, with or without loops, that I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times.

Comment: @drachenstern It isn't a big leap to go from arbitrary strings to spaces.

Comment: @drachenstern: I edited it (maybe after you saw it) to a new link that is only about single characters.

Comment: @Jeremiah, you did. @AtesGoral ~ You miss my point. Let's not do a link on arbitrary strings when the question was for spaces. Answer the specific question, not the advanced alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking around for ages, I just didn't think about searching for that specific wording. The best way to do it seems to be Array(int).join(" ").

Comment: @Gus That would be the fastest, yes. Most readable, maybe not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function spaces(size) {
    for(var output = ""; size > 0; size--) output += " ";
    return output;
}
```

A shorter version :)

```
function spaces(n) {
    for(var s="";n--;s+=" "){}return s;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty tricky. I like it. But won't output be out of scope outside the loop?

Comment: Nope, `var` will keep output in the local scope (`function spaces`). Apparently, using `let` instead of `var` would keep it within the block scope as well.

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of that. I know in C you should expect it to fall out of scope. I'm gonna have to remember that one. Thanks.

Comment: yay for the straightforward way not crashing the browser (altho an infinite loop may conceivably occur)

Comment: yeah the second version has that problem.. could put `n--&&n>0`. I just like my one line versions (without fancy smansy Array operations ;P)

Answer (score 4):

```
function nSpaces(n) {
    var s = '';
    while (n > 0 && n--) { s += ' '; }
    return s;
}
```

And then ...

```
var str = nSpaces(5);
```

---

For more information about the reverse while loop and looping in general, read here: 
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/looping-in-javascript/

Comment: @drachenstern I wouldn't call it a trick. It's just one way to loop.

Comment: It's a pretty common paradigm - the risk is if `n` is less than 0 to begin with.

Comment: @Hamish Ah yes, negative arguments create an infinite loop (which crashes my Chrome by the way LOL). I'll fix it.

Comment: @drachenstern The reverse loop really isn't that advanced. But I don't agree that beginners should not get a glimpse of the advanced "stuff". They of all people should see the tricks and hacks of JavaScript. Otherwise, how are they going to learn?

Comment: @drachenstern Yes, providing links to articles that give further explanations sounds like a good idea. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
function repeatCh( ch, num ) {    
  return new Array( num + 1 ).join( ch );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are faster ways to do this, but it's the same as you would do in any other procedural language. Notice that if you inject this into a page directly, it'll still show as only one space.

```
function gimmeSpaces(count){
   var returnValue = '';
     for (int i = 0;i<count;i++){ returnvalue += " ";}
   return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or there's always the array version:

```
function spaces(n) {
    var a = [ ];
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a.push(' ');
    return a.join('');
}
```

The basic idea is to build a list of `n` spaces ([`a.push(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) and then stick them all together at once at the end ([`a.join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)).

AFAIK, string concatenation (e.g. `s += ' '`) is slow in some IE versions and the array approach is faster. OTOH, that really shouldn't make much difference in this case so you should go with whatever approach is clearer.

Comment: links within parens and an explanation, "I hope you win" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that doesn't involve loops:

```
function getSpaces(n) {
    return new Array(n + 1).join(" ");
}
```

Alternative, optimistic version (if speed is important, and the max number of spaces you would ever need is known):

```
function getSpaces(n) {
    return "                 ".substr(-n);
}
```