# Multiple character for X number of times

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeat Character N Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)

For example:

```
var x = 5,
    char = 'F';

// here return 'FFFFFF'
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Hm. It's not an exact duplicate. ("F" vs "a").

Comment: Except this is repeat character N+1 times :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = 5;
var c = 'F';

return Array(x + 1).join(c);
```

From [Repeat Character N Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)

Comment: There is no `char` syntax in javascript. You need to use `var`. Read my revision.