# Create an array with same element repeated multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat

In Python, where `[2]` is a list, the following code gives this output:

```python
[2] * 5 # Outputs: [2,2,2,2,2]
```

Does there exist an easy way to do this with an array in JavaScript?

I wrote the following function to do it, but is there something shorter or better?

```
var repeatelem = function(elem, n){
    // returns an array with element elem repeated n times.
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        arr = arr.concat(elem);
    };

    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array

Comment: possible duplicate: [stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function fillArray(value, len) {
  if (len == 0) return [];
  var a = [value];
  while (a.length * 2 <= len) a = a.concat(a);
  if (a.length < len) a = a.concat(a.slice(0, len - a.length));
  return a;
}
```

It doubles the array in each iteration, so it can create a really large array with few iterations.

---

Note: You can also improve your function a lot by using `push` instead of `concat`, as `concat` will create a new array each iteration. Like this (shown just as an example of how you can work with arrays):

```
function fillArray(value, len) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(value);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: It's much more efficient to allocate all of the entries up front, with `arr = new Array(len);`, then assign to them by index in the loop, i.e. `arr[i] = value;`.  That way you only pay O(n) rather than having to keep reallocating the array as it grows.  In general, it's always better to avoid growing arrays by appending when possible.  If you know the final size, use it.

Comment: `Array.from({length:5}).map(x => 2)`

Comment: @noobninja: great solution; you should re-enter it as an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: Here's an optimised version of the latter:
`function fillArray(value, len) {
    for (let n = [], u = 0; u < len; u++) n.push(value);
    return n
}`

Answer (score 1281):

In ES6 using Array [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method

```js
console.log(
  Array(5).fill(2)
)
//=> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Internet Explorer and Opera don't support it yet.

Comment: Node.js <= 3 does not support this.

Comment: There is an existing [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.fill) for those lacking support.

Comment: Still out of luck if you want to (for example) fill in more than one value over and over, e.g.  [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: @Michael You can do it with `Array(5).fill([1,2,3]).flat()`. Note that [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is still very experimental and browser support is poor.

Comment: Note that the argument to `fill` is evaluated once, so `Array(9).fill(someMutable)` creates nine references to `someMutable` in the array (mutating one mutates 'them all').

Comment: why is `new` optional?

Comment: @CarlSmith You can pass anything to `fill` (to create an array with n number of slots), then populate those slots with a `map` to get around that limitation. For instance: `Array(4).fill('').map(() => randomWord())` will create an array like `['yoyo', 'slick', 'wombat', 'pretty']`

Answer (score 185):

```
>>> Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function(){return 5})
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> //Or in ES6
>>> Array.from({length: 10}, () => 5)
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Silly question, but why new Array(10).map does not work?

Comment: blazkovicz, see [zertosh's comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13735425/20712) for the reason.

Comment: With ES6, this can be "upgraded" to `Array(...Array(10)).map(() => 5)` with the spread operator or also to `Array.from(Array(10)).map(() => 5)`

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), you can just like this: `Array.from({length: 10}, () => 5);`

Comment: @blazkovicz Array(10) creates an array of `lenght = 10` without any enumerable properties. `.map` only works on enumerable properties. The `.apply` method takes this array, and maps it into an `arguments array` (an array-like object) to be passed to the `Array` constructor function. The arguments array can't be sparse so the missing properties get set to `undefined` and become enumerable. Now we can use `.map` like intended

Comment: Slight modification on @ChristopheVidal's comment:  `[...Array(10)].map(()=>5)`

Comment: Please, note that ES6 version isn't work in typescript!

Answer (score 133):

you can try:

```
Array(6).join('a').split(''); // returns ['a','a','a','a','a'] (5 times)
```

**Update (01/06/2018)**:

Now you can have a set of characters repeating.

```
new Array(5).fill('a'); // give the same result as above;
// or
Array.from({ length: 5 }).fill('a')
```

Note: Check more about [fill(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [from(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for compatibility and browser support.

**Update (05/11/2019)**:

Another way, without using `fill` or `from`, that works for string of any length:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(3)).map(_ => 'abc') // ['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

> Same as above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19892144/2492924). Adding for sake of completeness.

Comment: +1 for simple handling. A shame that you cannot create an array of empty strings out of that. Apart from that very smart...

Comment: Array(6).join('a').split('a')
gives me array of empty string.

Comment: This only works for 1 char strings, so it doesn't answer the question completely.

Comment: Is each "a" a separate object? Or does it reference the same object?

Comment: @AlfonsoVergara: In Javascript, String is a primitive (value-semantic) type; there's no way to get two strings to reference the same data (because strings *aren't* references in Javascript; they're values). You do have to watch out for reference semantics with objects and lists, but not with strings.

Answer (score 124):

### ...and Array.fill() comes to the rescue!

Used to write it all manually before knowing this one ‍♂️

```
Array(5).fill('')  // =>  ['','','','','']

Array(4).fill(0)  // =>  [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can also easily create a sequential array using fill() + map()

```
Array(4).fill('').map((_, i) => i + ' ') // =>  ['0 ','1 ','2 ','3 ']


Array(3).fill(' ').map((flower, i) => i + flower) // =>  ['0 ','1 ','2 ']
```

---

❗️Just be careful when creating objects and arrays using .fill() as they are **referenced types**❗️

That means Javascript will consider all the created items as being the same object (what may introduce unexpected bugs in case you want to further interact with the created objects)

```
// ❌ Careful when using .fill() with objects and arrays:

Array(3).fill({ value: 2 })  // =>  [{ value: 2 },{ value: 2 },{ value: 2 }]
```

The above line works, but it would be much safer to stick to the .fill().map() pattern. Like this:

```
//  Much better!

Array(3).fill().map(item => ({ value: 2 }))
```

Comment: Note that IE doesn't support it, but you can use a polyfill.

Comment: There's a lot of things IE doesn't support I guess... :)

Answer (score 55):

If you need to repeat an array, use the following.

```
Array(3).fill(['a','b','c']).flat()
```

will return

```
Array(9) [ "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Comment: Array(3).fill(['a','b','c']).flat()

Answer (score 49):

`Array.from({length:5}, i => 1) // [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

or create array with increasing value

`Array.from({length:5}, (e, i)=>i) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Nice,  this is the best approach if you need the element to dynamic

Comment: `Array.from({length:5}, i => 1)` => `i` is is `undefined` since it represents empty value
`Array.from({length:5}, (e, i)=>i)` => `e` is `undefined` since it represents empty value.

It should be `Array.from({length:5}, v => 1)` and `Array.from({length:5}, (v, i)=>i)`

Answer (score 41):

In [lodash](http://lodash.com/) it's not so bad:

```
_.flatten(_.times(5, function () { return [2]; }));
// [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

**EDIT**: Even better:

```
_.times(5, _.constant(2));
// [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

**EDIT**: Even better:

```
_.fill(Array(5), 2);
```

Comment: _.times(length, _.constant(value))

Comment: from the docs : 
_.fill(Array(3), 2);
Which is not far from ES6

Answer (score 19):

`[c] * n` can be written as:

```
Array(n+1).join(1).split('').map(function(){return c;})
```

so for `[2] * 5`

```
Array(6).join(1).split('').map(function(){return 2;})
```

Comment: Actually, wouldn't Array(6).join(2).split('') be easier? Why would you need the map?

Comment: that returns ["2", "2", "2", "2", "2"], instead of [2, 2, 2, 2, 2].

Answer (score 14):

You can also extend the functionality of Array like so:

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(val){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        this[i] = val;
    }
    return this;
};
// used like:
var arry = new Array(5)​.fill(2);
// or
var arry = new Array(5);
arry.fill(2);


​console.log(arry);​ //[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

I should note that extending the functionality of built-in objects can cause problems if you are working with 3rd-party libraries. Always weigh this into your decisions.

Comment: Note that if you pass an object into `fill` each index in the array will refer to the same object, so changing one will change all of them. This isn't too hard to solve if it becomes an issue.

Comment: I don't get why many javascript users are unaware of the requirement not to prototype native functions.

Comment: There is no such "requirement". It's merely a best practice when mixing libraries.

Comment: A [fill method](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.fill) has been added in ES6. So I wouldn't recommend adding your own stuff to the prototype, you're gonna overwrite the faster and more capable version.

Comment: @Janus you should post that answer.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen To avoid overwrite javascript or 3rd-party libraries you can check if exists prior to declare it. `if (!Array.prototype.fill) { }`

Comment: @Oliver why not just use a real polyfill then?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen What do you mean by "real polyfill"?. I used a polifyll. I mean: check for feature detection and implementation in case it is not.

Answer (score 10):

In the Node.js REPL:

```
> Array.from({length:5}).map(x => 2)
[ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ]
```

Comment: `Array.from({length: 5}, x => 2);` ref. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from)

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to repeat an *array* several times:

```
var arrayA = ['a','b','c'];
var repeats = 3;
var arrayB = Array.apply(null, {length: repeats * arrayA.length})
        .map(function(e,i){return arrayA[i % arrayA.length]});
// result: arrayB = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066663/667253)

Comment: in es6, you can do ["abc".repeat(3)](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features/blob/3478ee4c9cdcced16cd0325e5a7fb08e102063f1/README.md#math--number--string--array--object-apis)

Answer (score 6):

Use this function:

```
function repeatElement(element, count) {
    return Array(count).fill(element)
}
```

```
>>> repeatElement('#', 5).join('')
"#####"
```

Or for a more compact version:

```
const repeatElement = (element, count) =>
    Array(count).fill(element)
```

```
>>> repeatElement('#', 5).join('')
"#####"
```

Or for a curry-able version:

```
const repeatElement = element => count =>
    Array(count).fill(element)
```

```
>>> repeatElement('#')(5).join('')
"#####"
```

You can use this function with a list:

```
const repeatElement = (element, count) =>
    Array(count).fill(element)

>>> ['a', 'b', ...repeatElement('c', 5)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

No easier way. You need to make a loop and push elements into the array.

Comment: Thanks! Before I accept, is `push` better or `concat` better, in terms of efficiency?

Comment: CONCAT needs to inspect two arrays, PUSH just adds another element, so I would expect PUSH to be more efficient in general, but for the IDENTICAL DATA I think Guffa's answer nails it.

Comment: No need for loops, see my answer.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen, no need to loop unless you want an efficient way to do this action. Yours is one of the slower impementation you can find. push() to [] is the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered this today while trying to make a 2D array without using loops. In retrospect, joining a new array is neat; I tried mapping a new array, which doesn't work as map skips empty slots.

```
"#".repeat(5).split('').map(x => 0)
```

The "#" char can be any valid single character.
The 5 would be a variable for the number of elements you want.
The 7 would be the value you want to fill your array with.

The new fill method is better, and when I coded this I didn't know it existed, nor did I know repeat is es6; I'm going to write a blog post about using this trick in tandem with reduce to do cool things.

http://jburger.us.to/2016/07/14/functionally-create-a-2d-array/

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
"avinash ".repeat(5).trim().split(" ");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SpreadOpeator and the map() function to create an array with the same element repeated multiple times.

```
function fillArray(value,len){
       return [...Array(len).keys()].map(x=> value);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This function creates an array of (length) elements where each element equals (value) as long as (value) is an integer or string of an integer. Any decimal numbers will be truncated. If you do want decimal numbers, replace **"parseInt(**" with "**parseFloat(**"

```
function fillArray(length, intValue) {
     var vals = (new Array(length + 1)).join(intValue + '|').split('|').slice(0,length);
     for(var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
         vals[i] = parseInt(vals[i]);
     }
     return vals;
}
```

Examples:

```
fillArray(5, 7) // returns [7,7,7,7,7]
fillArray(5, 7.5) // returns [7,7,7,7,7]
fillArray(5, 200) // returns [200,200,200,200,200]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with the mentioned methods when I use an array like

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'];
var filled = array.fill(7);

//filled should be ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo']
```

To get this I'm using:

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(val){
    var l = this.length;
    if(l < val){
        for(var i = val-1-l; i >= 0; i--){
            this[i+l] = this[i % l];
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: This is nice, but should probably be named `cycle`.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner:

```
Array.prototype.map.call([]+Array(5+1),function(){ return '2'; })
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving on [Vivek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21291851/8535397), this works for strings of any length, to populate an array of length n: `Array(n+1).join('[string to be repeated][separator]').split('[separator]').slice(0, n)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var finalAry = [..."2".repeat(5).split("")].map(Number);
console.log(finalAry);
```

Comment: Please do not snippet dump on Stack Overflow.  Every answers should include some plain English explanation with the intent to educate and empower future readers.  How does it work? What advantage(s) does it have over other techniques on this bloated page? Are there fringe cases where this snippet is not advisable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a utlity belt like lodash/underscore you can do it like this :)

```
let result = _.map(_.times(foo), function() {return bar})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be used as a one-liner too:

```
function repeat(arr, len) {
    while (arr.length < len) arr = arr.concat(arr.slice(0, len-arr.length));
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn to string and return to array.

`['1', '2']` => `'1--2'` => `repeat`

`['1', '2'].join('--').repeat(2).split('--')` will return `['1','2','1','2',]`

Answer (score -1):

This could be another answers.

let cards = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"];

let totalCards = [...cards, ...cards, ...cards, ...cards];

Comment: How does this answer the asked question?  So, is your advice that if the asker wants something to occur 4 times in an array, they should declared `[value, value, value, value]`??? Not very elegant/scalable for the task.