# Repeat an array with multiple elements multiple times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat

In JavaScript, how can I repeat an array which contains multiple elements, in a concise manner?

In Ruby, you could do

```
irb(main):001:0> ["a", "b", "c"] * 3
=> ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

I looked up the lodash library, and didn't find anything that was directly applicable. [Feature request: repeat arrays.](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1436) is a feature request for adding it to lodash, and the best workaround given there is

```
const arrayToRepeat = [1, 2, 3];
const numberOfRepeats = 3;
const repeatedArray = _.flatten(_.times(numberOfRepeats, _.constant(arrayToRepeat)));
```

The questions [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295584/most-efficient-way-to-create-a-zero-filled-javascript-array) and [Create an array with same element repeated multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503146/create-an-array-with-same-element-repeated-multiple-times) focus on repeating just a single element multiple times, whereas I want to repeat an array which has multiple elements.

Using reasonably well-maintained libraries is acceptable.

Answer (score 32):

No need for any library, you can use `Array.from` to create an array of arrays you want repeated, and then flatten using `[].concat` and spread:

```js
const makeRepeated = (arr, repeats) =>
  [].concat(...Array.from({ length: repeats }, () => arr));
  
console.log(makeRepeated([1, 2, 3], 2));
```

On newer browsers, you can use `Array.prototype.flat` instead of `[].concat(...`:

```js
const makeRepeated = (arr, repeats) =>
  Array.from({ length: repeats }, () => arr).flat();
  
console.log(makeRepeated([1, 2, 3], 2));
```

Comment: you can make the code more concise if the `repeats` argument is changed to `length` :p

Comment: I did that originally but I thought it made the intent slightly less clear

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `Array` constructor along with its `fill` method to fill it a number of times of the array you want to repeat, then `concat` them (the subarrays) into a single array:

```
const repeatedArray = [].concat(...Array(num).fill(arr));
```

**Note:** On older browsers (pre-ES6), you can use `Function#apply` to mimic the rest syntax above (`concat` will be called with each of the sub arrays passed to it as argument):

```
var repeatedArray = [].concat.apply([], Array(num).fill(arr));
```

**Example:**

```js
const arrayToRepeat = [1, 2, 3];
const numberOfRepeats = 3;

const repeatedArray = [].concat(...Array(numberOfRepeats).fill(arrayToRepeat));

console.log(repeatedArray);
```

Answer (score 13):

```js
const repeat = (a, n) => Array(n).fill(a).flat(1)

console.log( repeat([1, 2], 3) )
```

---

Recursive alternative:

```js
const repeat = (a, n) => n ? a.concat(repeat(a, --n)) : [];

console.log( repeat([1, 2], 3) )
```

Answer (score 8):

My first idea would be creating a function like this

```js
let repeat = (array, numberOfTimes) => Array(numberOfTimes).fill(array).reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], [])
console.log(repeat(["a", "b", "c"], 3))
```

using the [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Ideally, instead of using reduce you could use [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)  but there's yet no support in browsers

Comment: Edited - added the default value for that case

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Array(3).fill(["a", "b", "c"]).flat()
```

```js
console.log( Array(3).fill(["a", "b", "c"]).flat() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious `[].concat` + `Array.from({length: 3}, …)`/`fill()` solution, using generators will lead to elegant code:

```
function* concat(iterable) {
    for (const x of iterable)
        for (const y of x)
            yield y;
}
function* repeat(n, x) {
    while (n-- > 0)
        yield x;
}

const repeatedArray = Array.from(concat(repeat(3, [1, 2, 3])));
```

You can also shorten it to

```
function* concatRepeat(n, x) {
    while (n-- > 0)
        yield* x;
}

const repeatedArray = Array.from(concatRepeat(3, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Though other methods works simply, these too.

`Array.fill()` and `Array.from()` in previous methods will not work in `IE`. [MDN Docs for Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

**Mehtod 1** : Loop and push ([Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Examples)) the same into the array.

```js
function mutateArray(arr,n)
{
    var temp = [];
    while(n--) Array.prototype.push.apply(temp,arr);
    return temp;
}
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(mutateArray(a,3));
```

**Method 2**: Join the array elements and [String.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to mutate the string and return the split string.

**Note**: The `repeat` method is not supported yet in `IE` and `Android webviews`.

```js
function mutateArray(arr,n)
{
    var arr = (arr.join("$")+"$").repeat(n).split("$");
    arr.pop(); //To remove the last empty element
    return arr;
}
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(mutateArray(a,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible natively in JS (Also operator overloading is not possible, so we can not use something like `Array.prototype.__mul__`), but we can create an Array with the proper target length, fill with placeholders, then re-map the values:

```js
const seqFill = (filler, multiplier) => 
  Array(filler.length * multiplier)
  .fill(1)
  .map(
    (_, i) => filler[i % filler.length]
  );

console.log(seqFill([1,2,3], 3));
console.log(seqFill(['a','b','c', 'd'], 5));
```

Or another way by hooking into the Array prototype, you could use the syntax of `Array#seqFill(multiplier)`, this is probably the closest you can get to ruby syntax (rb can do basically everything with operator overloading, but JS can't):

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'seqFill', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function(multiplier) {
    return Array(this.length * multiplier).fill(1).map((_, i) => this[i % this.length]);
  }
});

console.log([1,2,3].seqFill(3));
```