# Repeat every element in array based on object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array that I'm retrieving from an API. The array looks like this:

```json
[{
    "name": "Rachel",
    "count": 4,
    "fon": "46-104104",
    "id": 2
},
{
    "name": "Lindsay",
    "count": 2,
    "fon": "43-053201",
    "id": 3
},
{
    "name": "Michael",
    "count": 5,
    "fon": "46-231223",
    "id": 4
}]
```

Then I loop through the array to create an array containing only the names.

```js
function buildName(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    nameList.push(data[i].name)
  }
}
```

This also works so far, but I would like to create an array in which each name occurs as often as the object count says.

For example, the name Michael should appear five times in the array and Lindsay twice.

```json
[
  "Rachel",
  "Rachel",
  "Rachel",
  "Rachel",
  "Lindsay",
  "Lindsay",
  "Michael",
  "Michael",
  "Michael",
  "Michael"
  "Michael"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded your functions but you can use the map method

```
function buildName(data){
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      let numToLoop = data[i].count
      let name = data[i].name
        for (let z = 0; z < +numToLoop; z++){
          nameList.push(name)
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For each object create [a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) using `count`, and then [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it with the `name`.

If you use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate over the array of objects. It will return a new array of nested objects but then flatten them into a non-nested structure.

```js
const data=[{name:"Rachel",count:4,fon:"46-104104",id:2},{name:"Lindsay",count:2,fon:"43-053201",id:3},{name:"Michael",count:5,fon:"46-231223",id:4}];

const out = data.flatMap(obj => {
  return new Array(obj.count).fill(obj.name)
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner `while` loop inside the `for` loop:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Rachel",
    "count": 4,
    "fon": "46-104104",
    "id": 2
},
{
    "name": "Lindsay",
    "count": 2,
    "fon": "43-053201",
    "id": 3
},
{
    "name": "Michael",
    "count": 5,
    "fon": "46-231223",
    "id": 4
}]


function buildName(data){
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    let item = data[i];
    let count = item.count;
    while (count > 0) {
      result.push(item.name);
      count -= 1;
    }
  }
  return result;
}


console.log(buildName(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an inner loop with as many iterations as the `"count"` property in the object:

```
function buildName(data) {
    const nameList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i].count; j++) {
            nameList.push(data[i].name);
        }
    }

    return nameList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun

```
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import { chain, replicate } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';

const arr = ...
const result = pipe(
  arr,
  chain(i => replicate(i.count, i.name))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via creating an array with repeated names in this way:

```
Array(count).fill(name)
```

Then you have to spread it into resulting array.
You can try this one-liner

```
const getNames = (data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (names, { name, count }) => [...names, ...Array(count).fill(name)],
    []
  )
```

Note that a pure function is presented here, which is generally the preferred way of writing code.  However, updating your example code might look like this

```
const getNames = (data) =>
  data.reduce(
    (names, { name, count }) => [...names, ...Array(count).fill(name)],
    []
  )

function buildName(data) {
  nameList = getNames(data)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`.flapMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for that:

```js
const arr = [{ "name": "Rachel", "count": 4, "fon": "46-104104", "id": 2 }, { "name": "Lindsay", "count": 2, "fon": "43-053201", "id": 3 }, { "name": "Michael", "count": 5, "fon": "46-231223", "id": 4 }];

const result = arr.flatMap(({count, name}) => Array(count).fill(name));
console.log(result);
```

Effectively you turn every element into [an array of the the name property repeated `count` times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503146/create-an-array-with-same-element-repeated-multiple-times) which is then flattened into a single array.