# How to change the values of elements of an array at once in javascipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, assign

I want to change the values of elements of an array to the same number.
For eg:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 0;
arr[2] = 0;
```

Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: does this link help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503146/create-an-array-with-same-element-repeated-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
arr.fill(0);
```