# Idiom for "repeat n times"?

Tags: javascript

Here's a somewhat wasteful and impractical way to produce an array of 3 random numbers in JS:

```
[1, 1, 1].map(Math.random) // Outputs: [0.63244645928, 0.59692098067, 0.73627558014]
```

The use of a dummy array (e.g. `[1, 1, 1]`), just so that one can call `map` on it, is -- for sufficiently large *n* -- both wasteful (of memory) and impractical.

What one would like, would be something like a hypothetical:

```
repeat(3, Math.random) // Outputs: [0.214259553965, 0.002260502324, 0.452618881464]
```

What's the closest we can do using vanilla JavaScript?

I'm aware of libraries like Underscore, but I'm trying to avoid libraries here.

I looked at the answers to [Repeat a string a number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times), but it is not applicable in general. E.g.:

```
Array(3).map(Math.random) // Outputs: [undefined, undefined, undefined]
Array(4).join(Math.random()) // Outputs a concatenation of a repeated number
Array(3).fill(Math.random()) // Fills with the same number
```

Several other answers propose modifying a built-in class; a practice that I consider completely unacceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat Character N Times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times). That question is asking slightly more than yours, but the concept (creating an array of n elements) is the same. Ultimately, just use `Array(n + 1)`

Comment: Do you want integers? A random number between what and what?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I explicitly rejected `[1,1,1].map(Math.random)` in my question statement for being wasteful.  How is `Array(3).map(Math.random)` different?  Of course, I know that for *n*=3 the waste is negligible, but not so for larger *n*.

Comment: @PHPglue: you're taking too literally what was only a simple-to-describe example.

Comment: @kjo: The obvious difference is that you don't have to write every element explicitly. `Array(100)` is a helluva lot more terse than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... 100]`. As for this "waste" you speak of - I don't understand the problem. Do you think there is some magic way of doing what you want, *without* allocating an array?

Comment: And loop/push is out of the question?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: do you ***truly believe*** that it is ***necessary*** to ***allocate an array*** in order to repeat a function call *n* times???

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: certainly not, but it is not what I'd call an idiom...

Comment: @SimpleCoder This is definitely not a duplicate of that question. This is about calling a function multiple times, not repeating a value.

Comment: @kjo: No, no, no - let's stop moving the goal post. Every code example you posted produces an array. If that's not what you meant, and your claim of "repeat a function call n times" is true, then I'd refer you to the `for` loop. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: David Brown understood the question perfectly...

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this, an idiom, maybe a disgustiom: `var n = 5;
alert(String(Array(n+1)).split('').map(Math.random));`. Now please excuse me while I go wash my mouth out with JSON.

Comment: @kjo: That's nice, but let's not distract from the point. A better way of asking your question would have been, "How to fill an array with *n* invocations of a function", or something similar. "How to repeat something n times" is not accurate to what you were apparently looking for. That being said, I'm glad you found an answer that works for you.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: look at the accepted answer.  That's what I was looking for.  At least someone got it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Underscore.js has a [times](http://underscorejs.org/#times) function that does exactly what you want:

```
_.times(3, Math.random)
```

If you don't want to use Underscore, you can just write your own `times` function (copied and slightly simplified from the Underscore source):

```
times = function(n, iterator) {
  var accum = Array(Math.max(0, n));
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) accum[i] = iterator.call();
  return accum;
};
```

Comment: downvote because there are more current and better answers with less votes.

Answer (score 160):

It *can* be done using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but the array can't be empty. [Fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) it first:

```js
console.log(
    Array(3).fill().map(Math.random)
);
```

**Explanation:**

The `new Array(3)` constructor creates [a sparse array](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html) (or ["holey" array, as the V8 team calls them](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2017/09/elements-kinds-in-v8.html)) [with three holes in it and a length of three](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax). This means that it's equivalent to `[,,,]`, which creates `[<empty>, <empty>, <empty>,]` (note JavaScript's [trailing commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)). Note that an empty slot, i.e. a hole is not the same as `undefined` as an assigned value. `undefined` is an actual value, whereas `<empty>` is just a gap in the array.

`Array.prototype.map` is called [once for each element in the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description). But, because an empty array has no assigned values, the callback doesn't get called at all. For example, `[1,,2].map(v=>v*2)` would give `[2,,4]`; the middle slot is skipped, as it has a gap there.

Enter [`Array.prototype.fill(value, start?, end?)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill): with only one argument, it fills every slot in the array with the specified value. Technically, the first parameter is not optional, but by omitting it, `undefined` is used as the value. This is okay, because the value isn't being used anyway. This way `Array(3).fill()` gives us `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Now that the array has values in it, it can be mapped over, like seen above.

---

You could also [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the empty `array` into values of `undefined` before mapping:

```js
console.log(
    [...Array(3)].map(Math.random)
);
```

**Explanation:**

Array operators introduced in ECMAScript2015 or newer [treat holes in arrays as `undefined` values](http://2ality.com/2015/09/holes-arrays-es6.html#ecmascript-6-holes-are-treated-like-undefined-elements). `Array.prototype.map` was introduced in ES5 (I.E. [what preceded ES2015](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp)), where, confusingly, holes in arrays are to be skipped over, creating a little bit of inconsistency in JS Array functions depending on which edition of ECMAScript they were released in.

The spread operator `...` [was introduced in ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer), so as per spec, it converts any holes in the given array into values of `undefined`. In other words, `[...Array(3)]` gives us `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, just like `Array(3).fill()` did above.

---

Sometimes you may need to seed in numbers sequentially. As pointed out by [Kevin Danikowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8430249/kevin-danikowski), `Array.prototype.map` gives you that out of the box, as the second parameter is the current key:

```js
const Fibonacci = n => Math.round(((5**.5 + 1) / 2)**n / 5**.5);

console.log(
    Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => Fibonacci(++i))
);
```

Comment: Great job, no need for npm package added. Also, if you want to return something more complicated, in your map use `.map((_,index)=>returnItem)`

Comment: Love this! IMO, better than the accepted answer.  
To generate integers use something like:
`const getRandomIntArray = (max) => (
    [...Array(3)].map(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
    )
);`

Comment: Awesome! Just a quick note: `Array.prototype.fill` requires a parameter value, even though it works without it. (e.g. TS will warn you) Check out the details on [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#value)

Answer (score 27):

Maybe the `Array.from` callback can be of use:

```js
var result = Array.from(Array(3), Math.random);

console.log(result);
```

There is a slight advantage here over using `map`: `map` already needs an array *with all the entries* (maybe created with `fill` or the spread syntax), to then create the final array from that. So in total a `map` solution will create *n* entries *twice*. `Array.from` does not need an array with entries, just an object with a `length` property will do, and `Array(3)` is providing that.

So depending on your preferences, the above can also be done like this:

```js
var result = Array.from({length:3}, Math.random);

console.log(result);
```

Finally, if you would create a `repeat` function for this, you can name the argument `length` and use the ES6 short notation for object literals:

```js
const repeat = (length, cb) => Array.from({length}, cb);

const result = repeat(3, Math.random);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah it works just like `.map` on final array, tough from my experience a few developers use this and understand it at glance. But its pretty clean, disregarding readability for unexperienced devs

Answer (score 26):

shortmost elegant ES6:

```
let times = (n, f) => { while(n-- > 0) f(); }
```

oh, That's not for creating an array, but it's still neat!

```
times(3, () => print('wow'))
```

or Ruby style:

```
Object.assign(Number.prototype, { times(f) { x = this; while(x-- > 0) f(); }})
3..times(() => print('wow'))
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that `n-->0` is not some kind of arrow operator, it's `n-- > 0`. This is cool, though.

Comment: If you can assume `n` is an integer, you can remove the `>0` check because when `n` hits zero it will equate to false. Non-integer `n` will result in an infinite loop however.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol thanks! so it is not 'shortmost' but 'safemost' ;)

Comment: I feel very stupid after reading this answer and not understanding single line of it :(

Comment: @koolaang in the first insance, they're creating a function that takes two arguments, `n` and `f`, `n` being an integer, and `f` being a function, and calls `f` `n` times. (It is an ES6 Arrow Function) In the second instance, they're taking `Number.prototype`, which *all* JavaScript numbers inherit methods from, and adding a new method to it called `times` using `Object.assign`. Many would consider this bad practice though :)

Comment: neat solution :)

Answer (score 7):

A modern way to create that `repeat` function:

```
repeat = (n, cb) => {[...Array(n)].forEach(cb)}
```

You can then use it with:

```
repeat(3, _ => console.log(Math.random()))
```

Would output:

```
0.6324464592887568
0.5969209806782131
0.7362755801487572
```

Answer (score 6):

I like this way:

```
[...Array(5).keys()].forEach(index =>
  console.log(`do something ${index}`
)
```

Comment: This only covers half of the question. How would this be used to do anything 5 times, not just generate a sequential number.

Comment: And why spread the keys array into a new array? `Array(5).keys().map(...)` would suffice and avoid an extra array creation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```js
Iet res = 'n'.repeat(3).split('').map(Math.random)
```