# javascript async/await in a generic loop

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I want to make this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585993/1973680 synchronous.

Is this the correct implementation?

```
        let times= async (n,f)=>{while(n-->0) await f();} 

        times(5,()=>
               myfunc([1,2,3],err => err)
              )
```

`myfunc` is itself an async function awaiting for various other functions:

```
async myfunc(params,cb){

   await a( err => err )
   await b( err => err )
   await c( err => err )

}`
```

Comment: `async/await` doesn't make code synchronous. It just enables a more convenient way of writing asynchronous code. And yeah, that looks like it should work (why don't you just try it?), although I'd rather write `async () => await  myfunc([1,2,3],err => err)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "make synchronous"? Or is it a typo and you meant asynchronous?

Comment: That `err => err` callback you are passing but not using anywhere does not look like correct usage of `async function`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this the correct implementation?

Yes. `await` works in loops like you'd expect it to, if that was your actual question.
I would however recommend to write

```
async function times(n, f) {
    while (n-- > 0)
        await f();
}
```