# Dynamically add spaces between concatenated strings

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically add space between two concatenated strings or integers. For example, here is simply concatenating a string and an integer:

```
var name = "Bruce"
var age = 14
name + " " + age
=> 'Bruce 14'
```

I would like the space between name and age be dynamic. *e.g.:*

```
var name = "Bruce"
var age = 14
var numberOfSpaces = something
name + 4 spaces + age
=> 'Bruce    14'
```

One of the use cases is drawing bar charts in dc.js where I can put name at the bottom and the value at the top of the bar. But this is unrelated. I am just curious if there is a method.

Comment: Something like `[name, age, "thing"].join(" ")` ? That's not exactly *cleaner* though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeat Character N Times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [proposed `repeat()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), but it's implemented almost nowhere.

Meanwhile, you can write your own:

```
function repeatstr(ch, n) {
  var result = "";

  while (n-- > 0)
    result += ch;

  return result;
}

var name = "Bruce"
var age = 14
var numberOfSpaces = 4

var fullName = name + repeatstr(" ", numberOfSpaces) + age;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function to do it:

```
function spaces(x) {
    var res = '';
    while(x--) res += ' ';
    return res;
}

var name = "Bruce";
var age = 14;
name + spaces(4) + age;

> "Bruce    14"
```

I think this is the prettiest and easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = function(n) {return new Array(n + 1).join(",").replace(/,/g," ")};
var name = "Bruce";
var age = 14;
var numberOfSpaces = 4;
name + s(numberOfSpaces) + age;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update! The [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) has been supported by all major browsers for quite some time now.

You can just do:

```
var name = "Bruce";
var age = 14;
name + ' '.repeat(4) + age;
```