# In JavaScript, how can I replace all the letters of a string with a single character?

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is for example:

```
var variable = "Hello"
```

becomes

```
*****
```

i.e each letter replaced with an asterisk. In JS please.

Comment: You probably spent more time writing this question than it would've taken you to lookup an existing question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+replace+all+characters+of+a+string).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat `*` for the length of the input by way of an array

```
> var variable = "Hello"
> Array(variable.length + 1).join("*");
> "*****"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you..

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/[^abc]/g, "*");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to replace "Hello" with "*****" </p>

<p id="demo">Hello</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877479) answer can be helpful.

You can update the string with a new one that has as many characters as the initial string:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var my_char = "*";
str = Array(str.length+1).join(my_char);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a ES6 answer, to the ES5 one:

```
var foo = "Hello"; 
var bar  = "*".repeat(foo.length);
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat