# Javascript: Hang-Man Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making a simple hang-man game using a browser.

When the user clicks on a button, it calls a function `pickWord()`:

```
    <button onclick="pickWord()" id="restart">Pick A Word</button>
```

The function then picks a random word from the dictionary, assigns it to a variable, and creates the spaces ( _ _ _ _) for the word to put in an html table.

```
    function pickWord()
    {
        var word = dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random()*dictionary.length)];
        wordSpaces = "_" * word.length;
        document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces;

    }
```

This is not working: The spaces are not displayed on the table.

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoshKono/24eqxLpn/) to help solve the problem.

Comment: At least in your fiddle, you're missing a comma after "Hangman" in your array. You're also going to have an issue because `"_" * word.length;` won't work.

Comment: Ok thanks! Is there a way to make the number of spaces = the length of the word?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times) for that solution. `Array(word.length).join('_');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply multiplication to a string and a number, so you need to use a loop to build the `wordSpaces` string.

There is a comma missing after the first line in the `dictionary` array.

In your JSFiddle, the javascript code was wrapped inside the `onLoad` function, so you didn't have a pickWord in the global scope.

updated: https://jsfiddle.net/24eqxLpn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
function pickWord() {
    var word = dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random()*dictionary.length)];

    var wordSpaces = '';
    for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++) {
        wordSpaces += '_'; // append
    }

    document.getElementById('spaces').innerHTML = wordSpaces;

}
```

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Your first pb comes from your table, you missed a comma `,`
Javascript crashes after that.