# Converting strings into a series of underscores based on length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

So, as a relatively new programmer, I'm trying to create a very simple ASCII hangman game. I'm trying to figure out how to create a string of underscore's(_) based on the length of the word chosen.

For example, take the word Kaiser, I'd like to take, 'word.length(where word = "Kaiser")`and convert it to "`_ _ _ _ _ _`". Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's as easy as `var u = new Array("Kaiser".length).join('_')`, and based on that answer, this looks a lot like a duplicate of [**Repeat Character N Times**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first guess is something like this would work.

```
var underscored = string.split('').map(function(char) {
  return char = '_ ';
}).join('');
```

Get every character in the string with the `split` function, and change the state of every character, using the `map` function. However, this will just give us an array. We need to perform type conversion again to turn it back to a string. To do this, we can use the `join` method. The delimiter we join is simply an empty string `''`.

Another possibility is with the replace function

```
var underscored = string.replace(/./g, '_ ');
```

The regular expression here is very simple. The period `.` indicates any character. The `global(g)` flag means find all instances of the previous regex.

The second parameter of this function is what we want these characters to become. Since we want a space between underscores, this will be `_`.

Note that the `replace` method is not destructive. In other words, it does not modify the original array. You would need to store this in a separate variable. Because if you call `string` again, `kaiser` will be returned.

Comment: Ah beat me to it, I would suggest the `.replace()`

Comment: Or combining `.split` and regular expressions: `string.split(/./).join('_')` ;)

Comment: My apologies pawel. I just noticed that. I will fix that in the `map` method

Comment: Here's another one: `Array( string.length ).join('_ ')`

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "Kaiser";
var resStr = "";
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    resStr = resStr + " _";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace anything just create new string based on length of the first word, example :

```
var underscore_word = Array(word.length).join("_ ");
```

Take a look at **[Repeat Character N Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where @NathanP. ?? i can't see it.

Comment: Really, comment is not answer !.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm OK with this and I don't expect everyone to read every comment before posting. I don't know why you were downvoted, it's a legit and quite efficient solution.