# put spaces with some key to value

Tags: javascript, css

I use the following code to add space inside the inverted commas for some value ,there is nicer/elegant way to do it ?

```
text: x.fullPath + "                           " + x.name
```

Comment: Can you explain logic of space addition?

Comment: How many space do you want to add in between?

Comment: @ParkashKumar - lest say 15 ...

Comment: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/naxh2xt1/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use this:

```
text: x.fullPath + Array(30+1).join(" ") + x.name
```

where `30` is the amount of spaces

---

This would be a function:

```js
// text: addSpace(x.fullPath, x.name, 5)

function addSpace(stringA, stringB, spaceCount) {
  var spaces = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < spaceCount; ++i) {
    spaces += " "
  }
  return stringA + spaces + stringB
}

// Demo
alert(addSpace("test1", "test2", 30))
```

Comment: Array.join puts spaces between the items in the array, which means `Array(30).join(" ")` will produce 29 spaces.

Comment: @zzzzBov I overlooked that, thank you! - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1877479/4339170

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function which return the string joining the two values with the given number of space.

```
text: addSpace(x.fullPath, x.name, 5)
```

Will give you a new string joining these two values with 5 spaces.

You can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34494612/1496715) or

```
function addSpace(stringA, stringB, spaces){
   return x.fullPath + Array(spaces).join(" ") + x.name;
}
```

Comment: @Mark have you created one?

Comment: How would you suggest to do it elegantly,this was my question :)

Comment: @Mark thats what i have answered, check the updated code.

Comment: @CodeiSir hehe, i have given you credits :P , mark needs it badly.

Comment: @void well it's still wrong, but I prefere `Array(30).join(" ")` from my answer ;P