# Javascript: Replace x &nbsp with x spaces at beginning of string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string with an unknown number of spaces at the beginning.

I would like to replace each of the spaces with a `&nbsp;`.

ONLY the spaces at the beginning of the string should be replaced.

This:

```
'   This is a string with 3 spaces at the beginning';
```

Should translate to:

```
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a string with 3 spaces at the beginning'
```

And this:

```
'     This is a string with 5 spaces at the beginning';
```

Should translate to:

```
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a string with 5 spaces at the beginning'
```

I'm looking for a solution that **doesn't** required looping through the spaces of the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
str.replace(/^ */, function(match) {
  return Array(match.length + 1).join("&nbsp;")
});
```

This matches on zero or more spaces at the start of a string, then determines how many spaces there are (using `match.length`), then repeats `"&nbsp;"` the given number of times (using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877479/1317805)).

---

```js
var str = '     This is a string with 5 spaces at the beginning';

var result = str.replace(/^ */, function(match) {
  return Array(match.length + 1).join("&nbsp;")
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great answer. But note that joining the array returns one item less than the `match.length` count.
So maybe more accurate solution would be:
`Array(match.length + 1).join("&nbsp;")`

Comment: @Cobi yeah I noticed my error myself a couple of minutes ago but wasn't sure if you'd already seen it so didn't mention anything. The answer is already fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace only the first spaces.

Split it with regex and take the first value on array.

replace `/\s/g` with `&nbsp;` in the first part

Again, from the original word, replace `^/\s+/` (that is the starting space sequence) with the `&nbsp;` sequence word.

As I did in the code below

```js
var str="     This is a string with 5 spaces at the beginning";
str2=str.split(/[^\s]/)[0];
str2=str2.replace(/\s/g,'&nbsp;');
str=str.replace(/^\s+/,str2);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Absolutely unnecessary `split` step. Looks like you don't know how to use `replace` properly (using callback function).