# Create a string of specified copies of a given string

Tags: javascript, loops, push

I am trying to iterate over the original string 3 times. The result I get is:
["a","b","c","d",undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]

The correct result should be: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"]

```
function makeCopies (str, howmany) {
  let newCopy = [];
   for(let i = 0; i <  str.length * howmany; i++) {
   newCopy.push(str[i])
   } 
return newCopy;
}

console.log(makeCopies("abcd", 3))
```

I have tried many variations but nothing works, this is the closest I got.

Comment: With `i % str.length` you can get 0,1,2,3,0,1,2...

Comment: `str.length * howmany` is 16. When you get to, say, `i = 6` you're doing `str[6]`.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-a-string-in-javascript-a-number-of-times

Comment: I am not sure I understand....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has a repeat Method on Strings. You can just use `"abcd".repeat(3)` and you will get "abcdabcdabcd". If you really want an array of the chars, you can spread the string into an array with `[..."abcd".repeat(3)]`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has a nice utility for this [String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). You can then split it on every character if an array is what you want.

```js
console.log("abcd".repeat(3).split(""))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this one.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the array is becoming 12 when you multiply `str.length * howmany`, and when it gets further than the fourth value it can't find anything and so becomes undefined.

A solution is you can wrap the main loop in another loop which will run `howmany` times.

```
function makeCopies (str, howmany) {
   let newCopy = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
       for(let j = 0; j <  str.length; j++) {
            newCopy.push(str[j])
        } 
    }
    return newCopy;
  }

  console.log(makeCopies("abcd", 3))
```

Comment: I thought it would continue looping again through the same string., just like it does with arrays? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't loop back over itself. The `for loop` in your question essentially looks like this: `for(let i = 0; i <  12; i++) {`, and so the loop will be looking for elements in the array at indexes higher than the indexes available in the array.

Comment: Thanks I understand now, great.

Comment: No worries mate.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const makeCopies = (string, count) => new Array(count).join(string).split('');

console.log(makeCopies('abcd', 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don’t you use `repeat()` ?

```
const res = "abc".repeat(3); // abcabcabc
```

If you need it as array, you can:

```
res.split(""); // ["a", "b", "c", ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating outside the bounds of original string

```
str[i]; // i <  str.length * howmany;
```

Try create two cycles instead:

```
for(let i = 0; i < howmany; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
    newCopy.push(str[j])
  }
}
```