# How to repeat a letter inside a string?

Tags: javascript

lets say the input is

```
let word = 'I Lo1ve Co4ding'
```

the output would be `I Loove Coooooding`

so repeating `x` letters after putting a number after

Still don't understand how it works and how to replace it mid string.

Comment: find the index of the number. Find previous character and repeat it. Can be done with a replace() and function.

Comment: Note that you cannot *change* the string; you'll have to make a new string.

Comment: *"and how to replace it mid string"* - Don't.  Create a new string by looping over the characters in the existing one and performing logic when one of those characters is a number.  (Maybe creating an array of characters along the way and then combining them into one resulting string afterward.)

Comment: Use the available [`String`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) and [`RegExp`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#instance_methods) methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat a string in JavaScript a number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-a-string-in-javascript-a-number-of-times)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the callback function argument in [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and call [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) on the first matching group (letter) and pass the second matching group (number) plus 1.

```js
const expandStr = (str) =>
  str.replace(/([a-z])(\d+)/gi, (g, g1, g2) => g1.repeat(+g2 + 1));

console.log(expandStr('I Lo1ve Co4ding'));
```

### Caveat

As suggested in the comments, you may use the following:

```js
/(\p{L})(\p{N}+)/gu
```

In place of:

```js
/([a-z])(\d+)/gi
```

Explanation:

- `\p{L}` – matches a single code point in the category "letter"
- `\p{N}` – matches any kind of numeric character in any script
- `\p{S}` – symbols e.g. emoji

```js
const expandStr = (str) =>
  str.replace(/(\p{L}|\p{S})(\p{N}+)/gu, (g, g1, g2) => g1.repeat(+g2 + 1));

console.log(expandStr('I Lo1ve Co4ding'));
console.log(expandStr('I give ️ I saw 1!')); // Works with emoji
```

Please refer to ["Unicode Categories"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to learn more.

Alternative pattern: `/([^(\p{N}|\s)])(\p{N}+)/gu`

### Tokenizing

Here is a more traditional example that incorporates loops. It does not use regular expressions, but follows a tokenizer (parser) approach.

**Note:** Keep in mind that this naïve example does not account for Unicode.

```js
const
  NUMBER_RANGE_START         = '0' .charCodeAt(0), //  48
  NUMBER_RANGE_END           = '9' .charCodeAt(0), //  57
  LETTER_UPPER_RANGE_START   = 'A' .charCodeAt(0), //  65
  LETTER_UPPER_RANGE_END     = 'Z' .charCodeAt(0), //  90
  LETTER_LOWER_RANGE_START   = 'a' .charCodeAt(0), //  97
  LETTER_LOWER_RANGE_END     = 'z' .charCodeAt(0), // 122
  WHITESPACE_CARRIAGE_RETURN = '\r'.charCodeAt(0), //  13
  WHITESPACE_LINE_FEED       = '\n'.charCodeAt(0), //  10
  WHITESPACE_SPACE           = ' ' .charCodeAt(0), //  32
  WHITESPACE_TAB             = '\t'.charCodeAt(0); //  9


const codeInRange = (code, start, end) => code >= start && code <= end;

const charInRange = (char, start, end) => codeInRange(char.charCodeAt(0), start, end);

const isNumber = (char) =>
  charInRange(char, NUMBER_RANGE_START, NUMBER_RANGE_END);

const isUpperLetter = (char) =>
  charInRange(char, LETTER_UPPER_RANGE_START, LETTER_UPPER_RANGE_END);

const isLowerLetter = (char) =>
  charInRange(char, LETTER_LOWER_RANGE_START, LETTER_LOWER_RANGE_END);

const isLetter = (char) => isLowerLetter(char) || isUpperLetter(char);

const isWhiteSpace = (char) => {
  switch (char.charCodeAt(0)) {
    case WHITESPACE_CARRIAGE_RETURN:
    case WHITESPACE_LINE_FEED:
    case WHITESPACE_SPACE:
    case WHITESPACE_TAB:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
};

const expandStr = (str) => {
  const result = [];
  let index, char, prevChar, count, step;
  for (index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
    char = str[index];
    if (
      isNumber(char) &&
      (
        isLetter(prevChar) ||
        (
          !isWhiteSpace(prevChar) &&
          !isNumber(prevChar)
        )
      )
    ) {
      count = parseInt(char, 10);
      for (step = 0; step < count; step++) {
        result.push(prevChar);
      }
    } else {
      result.push(char);
    }
    prevChar = char;
  }
  return result.join('');
};

console.log(expandStr('I Lo1ve Co4ding')); // I Loove Coooooding
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask where does the d+ and the gi came from. Is it just for grouping?

Comment: @RizkyAmanatama the `\d` portion of the regex is a short-hand for `[0-9]` (any number). The `gi` portion are expression flags. The `g` means global (match all occurrences) and the `i` means that the expression is case-insensitive. See: [_Advanced searching with flags_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags)

Comment: @RizkyAmanatama See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/4642212), the [guide on MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and the [regex tag wiki](/tags/regex/info) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](//regex101.com).

Comment: Consider some alternatives: `/(.)([0-9]+)/gsu` for any symbol, not just letters from `a` to `z`; `/(\p{L})([0-9]+)/gu` for only letters, but not restricted to the ones from `a` to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit longer way as from [Mr.Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187781/215552). But I think foreach loops make for good readability and you will see how it works.

```js
const word = 'I Lo1ve Co4ding'

function rewrite(w) {
  const arr = [...w];
  let n = [];
  arr.forEach((s,i) => {
    if(! isNaN(s) && s != ' ') {
      n.push(arr[i-1].repeat(s));
    } else {
      n.push(s);  
    }
  });
  return n.join('');
}
console.log( rewrite(word) );
```